# Get an array of list element contents in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a structure like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>text1</li>
  <li>text2</li>
  <li>text3</li>
</ul>
```

How do I use javascript or jQuery to get the text as an array?

```
['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
```

My plan after this is to assemble it into a string, probably using `.join(', ')`, and get it in a format like this:

```
'"text1", "text2", "text3"'
```

Answer (score 147, accepted):

```
var optionTexts = [];
$("ul li").each(function() { optionTexts.push($(this).text()) });
```

...should do the trick. To get the final output you're looking for, `join()` plus some concatenation will do nicely:

```
var quotedCSV = '"' + optionTexts.join('", "') + '"';
```

Comment: Does jQuery guarantee an order to the elements returned by the query? I would assume that the order returned is the same as the ordering in the DOM (ie text1, text2, text3), but I don't know what to look for in the documentation to see if this is true.

Comment: I've never seen it traverse the DOM in any other way that normal reading order. So although I can't prove it, I would bet the farm that it alwaays traverses the DOM top to bottom :)

Comment: Isn't $.each considered to have bad performance? If yes, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: How many list items do you have that this is an issue, @Daniel? Yeah, there are other ways to do the same thing (you could use $.map() to generate the array in one go), but they amount to the same thing.

Comment: @Shog9: I wish to push a dictionary to the list taking values from two different columns from each rows of a table.
Isn't there easier way to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post that as a separate question, @ln2khanal, and include an example of what you're looking to accomplish.

Answer (score 73):

Without redundant intermediate arrays:

```
var arr = $('li').map(function(i,el) {
    return $(el).text();
}).get();
```

See jsfiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cC8fT/)

Comment: You miss `.get()` at the end.

Comment: Based on Felix Klings suggestion:
    arr = $('li').map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

Comment: i dont understand why "get function" is necessary.

Comment: Yeah, what is the .get() for?

Comment: Are you sure $(this) refers to the item being iterated? According to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/, this refers to the global object.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/map/ explains why there's a .get() necessary ("As the return value is a jQuery-wrapped array, it's very common to get() the returned object to work with a basic array.").

Comment: The worse thing is, that the iterator is wrong, you need to switch the element and index, so that it says function(i, el).

Comment: @Kitto I saw the same thing, after spending 5+ minutes.

Answer (score 15):

And in clean javascript:

```
var texts = [], lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i=0, im=lis.length; im>i; i++)
  texts.push(lis[i].firstChild.nodeValue);

alert(texts);
```

Answer (score 14):

kimstik was close, but not quite.

Here's how to do it in a convenient one-liner:

```
$.map( $('li'), function (element) { return $(element).text() });
```

Here's the full documentation for jQuery's map function, it's quite handy: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Just to answer fully, here's the complete functionality you were looking for:

```
$.map( $('li'), function (element) { return $(element).text() }).join(', ');
```

Comment: I just saw this here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856283/jquery-collect-value-of-list-items-and-place-in-array) and was gonna repost since it's a great trick to know

Comment: My way should be little bit faster.. or not?

Comment: kimstik, according to Benchmark.js, my function call does 11,252 / 9,685 ops/sec for Opera and Chrome respectively, whereas the method call you posted does 9,666 / 9,083 ops/sec on a list of 40 items. I think the difference comes from the conversion from jQuery element list to Array in your example, if that helps.
They're very close, so pick whichever suits your coding style better :)

Answer (score 6):

```
var arr = new Array();

$('li').each(function() { 
  arr.push(this.innerHTML); 
})
```

Comment: Instead of relying on innerHTML, you should change "this" to a jQuery object and use the jQuery native text method. $(this).text()

Comment: why? eventually $(this).html() will use the native method

Comment: In this case it's better to use [] instead of the new Array() -
[What’s the difference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1273936/3183606)

Answer (score 3):

You may do as follows. 
one line of code will be enough

- `let array = $('ul>li').toArray().map(item => $(item).html());`
- Get the interested element

  1. get children
  2. get the array    from toArray() method
  3. filter out the results you want

```js
let array = $('ul>li').toArray().map(item => $(item).html());
console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>text1</li>
  <li>text2</li>
  <li>text3</li>
</ul>
```