# Does Javascript's new operator do anything but make life difficult?

Tags: javascript

I come from the traditional web developer background where I can by no means claim to really know anything about Javascript, however I am trying.

I currently have what I would describe as a fairly novice understanding of JQuery, a slightly better understanding of closures, and I've read through, and feel like I am fairly clear on Douglas Crockford's "Javascript: The Good Parts".

I've been building up some fairly javascript intensive pages lately and I'm actually pretty satisfied with the results.  One thing that stands to notice is that I managed to do the whole thing with almost no global functions and without using the new operator even once.

As a matter of fact, from my reading of the above-mentioned book, the operator does nothing that you could not do another simpler way and forces you to hack the 'this' variable.

So is there something I'm missing?  Does the new operator actually serve a purpose or is it just a trick to make OO programmers comfortable in what is at heart a functional language?  Would I be better off striking it entirely from my JS vocabulary?

Comment: Not to be overly critical, but note <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming">Functional programming</a> vs. <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming">procedural programming</a>

Sorry, feeling picky today...

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean Kendrick, are you saying that I should have linked the term "functional"?

Comment: Apparently comments aren't parsed the same way...

Functional Programming: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming

Procedural Programming:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming

I knew what you meant though, and it's to let you do OO type stuff with the language, which makes many people more comfortable and makes it easier to use for a lot of tasks.

Comment: Kendrick, are you saying JavaScript is not a functional language? I think it is.

Comment: I don't see how you could do it yourself, the biggest problem with prototypal inheritance for me is dropping real construction args, it is imo that a class should enforce its creation (as much as reasonable) by its rules.. being able to create an object that is 'uninitialized' just makes it harder to discover bugs.. and the specification initialization pattern is an ugly hack.

Comment: This has been answered *really well* already, including addressing Crockford's opinion on `new`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful

Answer (score 8):

First of all, kudos on reading Javascript: The Good Parts it's a great book on the language.

To answer your question, the `new` operator is required if you want to make use of prototypal inheritance.  There is no other way to have an object "inherit" from another.  That being said, you can copy properties from one object to another that would remove the need for the operator in some cases.

For example, a classical approach would use the following:

```
function MyClass() {};
MyClass.prototype.sayHello = function() {
   alert('hello');
};


var o = new MyClass();
o.sayHello();
```

You can achieve relatively the same thing as follows:

```
function MyClass() {
   return { 
      sayHello: function() {
         alert('hello');
      }
   };
}

var o = MyClass();
o.sayHello();
```

Comment: Actually, you can avoid using new by setting the prototype property directly on an object.  This has the unfortunate side effect of causing o.hasOwnProperty("prototype") to return true, where it would return false if new was used.

Comment: Thanks Bryan.  Wouldn't you just have your function return the function you want to "inherit" from and add whatever new functionality you want directly?  Isn't that the more natural way of achieving the same thing?

Comment: Frank: Actually assigning the prototype property on an object does not make the object inherit from that prototype.  You're correct in that o.hasOwnProperty('prototype') would indeed return true.

Comment: George: Returning the function would simply return a reference to the function not a new distinct object.  If you were to add methods to that function then all references to that function would see them.

The typical functional inheritance pattern is the "base" function return an object.  Inheritees simply call the base function and augment that object returned with new functionality.

Comment: While this is true to some degree, to say these two statements are equal is incorrect. There are huge memory implications. If you create 1000 of each, the first version will share references to the underlying prototype function, whereas the second will create a new reference for every instance. If you create a lot of dynamic objects, you're in for a world of hurt.

Here's a good thread about it:
http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-spinoffs/browse_thread/thread/58acd82eeb5afcc9/ede972acab3df08d?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=when+claiming+wrong#ede972acab3df08d

Comment: jvenema: You are absolutely correct.  Not only are there memory implications there are also performance implications as well.  It's much cheaper to hook up a single pointer than it is to build up a large structure.

Answer (score 2):

You brought up Crockford's "JavaScript: The Good Parts."

New is a bad part. Page 114. I don't use it. (Well, almost never.)

Crockford does use it (in his beget() method).

Definitely don't use it when you can use something else. Create objects and arrays with object and array literals.

Comment: Haha.  Actually for a book with "The Good Parts" in the title there's an awful lot of discussion of all the bad parts (as in, most of the book).  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Just to clarify the usage in `beget` for those who haven't read the book, since there's no (standard) way to set an object's prototype, `new` is the only way to do it. The `beget` function uses `new` to create an object with a specified prototype. ECMAScript 5 will have a built-in function called `Object.create` that does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the `new` operator. To me, Crockford is unconvincing on the subject. Whenever you create an object you will either use `new` somewhere in your code or use it implicitly by creating literals (e.g. object literals such as `{a: 1}` or array literals such as `[a, b, c]`).

Comment: That is not at all true Tim. Like I said, I've managed to do just fine without it.  You use a closure instead.

Comment: @Tim Here you go: http://pastebin.com/f1d6664e0 each time you call NotificationsDisplay() you get back an object/function with its own private variables, methods and even a public method.

Comment: "When you create an array using

var a = [];
You're telling the interpreter to create a new runtime array. No extra processing necessary at all. Done.

If you use:

var a = new Array();
You're telling the interpreter, I want to call the constructor "Array" and generate an object. It then looks up through your execution context to find the constructor to call, and calls it, creating your array." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/whats-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-arr/1273936#1273936

Comment: @George: Yes, you can define functions without the `new` keyword, and it's true that I didn't mention that. However, you certainly wouldn't want to create all your (not necessarily callable) objects as functions just to avoid using the `new` keyword, would you?

@Nosredna: I didn't think I was arguing about the relative merits of `var a = new Array()` versus `var a = []`. I'm certainly not arguing for the former over the latter. I was pointing out that the latter syntax is defined in the ECMAScript spec as doing the same thing as `new Array()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great article on prototype.js's implementation of the typical OO structuring. This wouldn't be possible without the "new" operator.

http://prototypejs.org/learn/class-inheritance

I highly recommend reading the prototype.js source. jQuery is amazing, and highly popular, but some of the things that have been done in prototype just have no comparison** elsewhere, in particular their class structuring.

**Some people might argue that some of what prototype does shouldn't be found elsewhere - that's a different question. But for sheer understanding of what's possible with javascript, prototype is the way to go, IMHO.