# Question about the use of 'new' operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript

From Mozilla documentation I learn about the new operator through this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

```
function Car(make, model, year) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
}

const car1 = new Car('Eagle', 'Talon TSi', 1993);

console.log(car1.make);
// expected output: "Eagle"
```

But I also can do this without using 'this' and 'new' operator by doing:

```
var Car = (make, model, year) => ({make, model, year})
var car1 = Car('Eagle', 'Talon TSi', 1993)
console.log(car1.make)
```

If I can accomplish the same result without using 'this' and 'new' operator, then what's the point of using them in the first place? Or do I missed something important?
Thanks. I'm sorry for the noob question.

Comment: One issue is your example is not complicated enough and they do not behave the same way.

Comment: There is a few reason, but mostly, using the second method is not intuitive. You might as well create an anonymous object and pretend it's a `Car`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744426/does-javascripts-new-operator-do-anything-but-make-life-difficult :-)

Comment: @epascarello has given a nice example. And here's another good post about class vs function in ES6 Javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099721/javascript-what-is-the-difference-between-function-and-class

Comment: Functionally one difference would be that `Car()` would not inherit any prototype properties/methods whereas `new Car()` would. I personally really prefer `class` declarations

Comment: Could you specify the title of your post to be more precise about what you are asking about?

Answer (score 1):

You have the same doubt that most beginners have, the class declaration by function and instantiation, and a function returning an object are very different.

```
function ClassName(params) {
    this.params = params;
}
```

This creates a class with the name `ClassName` and saying `new ClassName` returns an instance of the class `ClassName`, but the other thing you wrote is:

```
var ClassName = (params) => ({params: params});
```

What this means is that it creates a function and sets its return value to the object containing the params.

Pros and Cons:

1st method:
Pros: You can easily see that an object is an instance of another object(particularly, a class) by just saying `ClassInstance instanceof CLassName`, in your case, `car1 instanceof Car` which returns a boolean
Cons: (Till now, I didn't get any Cons with this method, if you have any Cons with this method, please comment, and I would take them under consideration)

---

2nd method:
Pros: Each created Object is of its own and does not have a relationship with same looking other object created by the same function (I don't know, how this would be helpful, but in some cases, it might be helpful)
Cons: You can't check that the object is the same(or instance of the same parent) by using `ClassInstance instanceof Class`, it would simply return false, and also it would not create an instance, it would just create an object