# What is the difference between Array() and [] in Javascript and why would I use one over the other?

Tags: javascript, arrays, literals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between “Array()” and “[]” while declaring a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/whats-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-arr)

In JavaScript you can create a new array like:

```
var arr = new Array();
```

or like:

```
var arr2 = [];
```

What is the difference and why would you do one over the other?

Comment: As far as I know, it does the same thing. Use whichever you prefer.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/whats-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-arr/1273936#1273936

Comment: wow, insane that the dupe detector didn't detect this when I was asking the question. The questions are nearly identical...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new Array(2)` proudces an array of size *2*, containing two `undefined`s.  `[2]` produces an array of size *1*, containing number *2*. `new Array` IMO doesn't fit with the spirit of JavaScript, even though it may make array construction much more findable.  That may or may not be of any importance (I use literals almost exclusively in JavaScript for all applicable types, and I've authored/maintained large pieces of JavaScript [30-50 KLOC] successfully).

*edit* I guess the reasons seasoned javascript programmers avoid `new Array` syntax are:

- it doesn't behave uniformly across argument numbers and types (`(new Array(X)).length == 1` for any `X` *as long as* `typeof(X) != "number"`
- it's more verbose and the only thing you gain is the irregularity

Comment: The first bullet point is perfect. That's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another (minor) reason to use `[]` in preference to `new Array()` is that `Array` could potentially be overridden (though I've never seen it happen) and `[]` is guaranteed to work.

```
Array = "something";
var a = new Array(); // Fails
var b = []; // Works
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe they're identical. I never use new Array();

Comment: Agree, two ways to make the same thing

Comment: but WHY don't you use new Array()? I know most "experienced" JavaScript developers don't, but why not?