# Difference between "new Array(..)" and "[..]" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is

```
var myCars=new Array("Saab","Volvo","BMW");
```

and

```
var myCars=["Saab","Volvo","BMW"];
```

exactly the same ?

Comment: You can get some answers here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/whats-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-arr

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, for that case they are the same.

There is a difference if you have only one item, and it's numeric. This will create an array with a single item:

```
var myNumbers = [42];
```

but this will create an array with the length 42:

```
var myNumbers = new Array(42);
```

Comment: The second example will not really have `42` items, only its `length` will be `42`. The properties from `0` to `41` don't exist in the object, e.g.: `new Array(42).hasOwnProperty('0'); // false`.

Comment: @CMS: Yes, you are right. Arrays in Javascript are a bit special in that way... I adjusted the answer.

Comment: @Guffa, another thing, the new third example is not right, both, the literal notation and the use of the `Array` constructor will generate an array with *one* element, that is the inner `[1,2,3]` array, e.g. `new Array([1,2,3]).length == 1`. The behavior described is only possible through something like `Array.apply(null, [1,2,3]);`

Comment: @CMS: It looks like the [Mozilla Dev Center got this one wrong](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Specifying_a_single_parameter) as well: `... The following code creates an array of five elements: var billingMethod = new Array(5);`

Comment: @Daniel, yeah, I think this is one of those *myths* that are out there all over the place hehe

Comment: @CMS: Yes, you are right. I was looking at Microsoft's documentation, but the constructor that handles an array differently only exists in some implementations of Jscript.

Comment: whats the use of creating and array of length 42 if its empty ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they are. However be aware that when you pass just a single numeric parameter to the `Array` constructor, you will be specifying the initial `length` of the array, instead of the value of the first item. Therefore:

```
var myCars1 = new Array(10);
```

... will behave differently from the following array literal:

```
var myCars2 = [10];
```

... note the following:

```
console.log(myCars1[0]);          // returns undefined
console.log(myCars1.length);      // returns 10
console.log(myCars2[0]);          // returns 10
console.log(myCars2.length);      // returns 1
```

That is one reason why it is often recommended to stick to the array literal notation: `var x = []`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are the same. There is no primitive form of an Array, as arrays in JavaScript are always objects. The first notation (`new Array` constructor syntax) was used heavily in the early days of JavaScript where the latter, short notation was not supported well.

Note that there is one behavioural difference: if you pass a single, numeric argument to `new Array`, like `new Array(20)`, it will return a new array pre-initialised with that number of elements from `0` to `n - 1`, set to `undefined`.

Comment: and how is that usefull at all  ?   am refering to your 2nd paragraph