# Convert range of dates to an array with all days between

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm stacked with one problem.

I have an array of data ranges:

```
var range_date_off=['31/03/2013','03/04/2013'];
```

I need to convert this into this:

```
var dates_off=['31/03/2013','01/04/2013','02/04/2013','03/04/2013'];
```

I started doing it with a loop, but the problem becomes when the month jumps to the other, any idea?

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: [javascript - get array of dates between 2 dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413590/javascript-get-array-of-dates-between-2-dates?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using [`date.js`](http://www.datejs.com/) here:

```
range = ['31/03/2013','03/04/2013']

begin = Date.parseExact(range[0], 'dd/MM/yyyy')
end   = Date.parseExact(range[1], 'dd/MM/yyyy')

dates = []

while(begin <= end) {
    dates.push(begin.toString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
    begin.addDays(1)
}
```

Result:

```
["31/03/2013", "01/04/2013", "02/04/2013", "03/04/2013"]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is parsing the date using regx

```
var range_date_off=['31/03/2013','03/04/2013'];
var d1 = parseDate(range_date_off[0])
var d2= parseDate(range_date_off[1])

var days= [];
for (var dt = d1; dt <= d2; dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1)) {
    var fdt = new Date(dt)
    days.push ( fdt.getDate() + "/" + (fdt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + fdt.getFullYear());
}

function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1]-1, parts[0]); 
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning (for people who might wonder how this works), that JS Date object handles exceeding boundaries itself – if `dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1)` is called on 31th of March, then adding a day this way automatically switches to the 1st of April.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using UTC arithmetic:

```
var start = Date.UTC(2013, 2, 31);
var end = Date.UTC(2013, 3, 3);
var currDate = start;
var dates = [];
while (currDate <= end) {
    var d = new Date(currDate);
    dates.push((d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear()));
   currDate += (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
}
```

Note, javescript months start at 0 !

http://jsfiddle.net/hKxzw/

Comment: Not every day has 86,400 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

Month check .... if month = [1,3,5,6,7,8,10,12] must not be greater than 31 days and so on ....