# Dates between two dates

Tags: javascript, date

I have for example two dates:

```
var first = '2013-07-30';
var second = '2013-08-04';
```

How can i show all dates between `first` and `second`?
This should return me:

```
2013-07-30
2013-07-31
2013-08-01
2013-08-02
2013-08-03
2013-08-04
```

In PHP I can get dates to `strtotime` and use a `while` loop. But how can I do it in jQuery?
I would like have this in array.

Comment: What you have did so far! Can you show your effort.

Comment: You'll get your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413590/javascript-get-array-of-dates-between-2-dates

Comment: Use PHP code to generate it, and get it into jQuery by a static PHP code generated array. Or transport the data by JSON?

Comment: @MikedeKlerk: Talk about overkill :)

Comment: Show your code then we would be able to help you in your own way.

Answer (score 8):

```
    var day = 1000*60*60*24;
    date1 = new Date('2013-07-30');
    date2 = new Date("2013-08-04");


    var diff = (date2.getTime()- date1.getTime())/day;
    for(var i=0;i<=diff; i++)
    {
       var xx = date1.getTime()+day*i;
       var yy = new Date(xx);

       console.log(yy.getFullYear()+"-"+(yy.getMonth()+1)+"-"+yy.getDate());
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I want to ask what is the use of this line `var day = 1000*60*60*24;` and `var xx = date1.getTime()+day*i;` thank you

Comment: Var day is total microseconds in a day 
var xx is adding days to a specific date.