# Meteor Js - Display documents associated to a day

Tags: meteor, meteor-packages

I'm fairly confused as to which is the best way of doing this, since I didn't manage to find a package that solves this easily and other answers of similar problems don't address this properly.

**I need to have a template that lists days and display all the documents created on each single day**, for example:

10/27/2015
- Document A
- Document B

10/26/2015
- Document C
- Document D
- Document E

Or, less vaguely:

10/23/2014
- John Smith received 10 points on Basquet
- Paul Atreides received 20 points on Future Telling

10/21/2014
- Heisenberg received 25 points on National Trade
- etc.

Being the displayed document something like a 'Reports' collection that joins 'Players' with 'Activities', for example.

What is the proper way of achieving this functionality? 
I guess creating a Days Collection is not the best option.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can just create an *array* of days in your template helper, iterate over that with `{{#each}}` then have another helper that returns a cursor of documents for each day.

**html:**

```
<template name="docsByDay">
{{#each days}}
  Date: {{this}} <!-- 'this' will be an individual date ->
  {{#each documents this}}
    {{content}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
</template>
```

Replace `{{content}}` with whatever field(s) you want to display from your collection.

**js:**

```
Template.docsByDay.helpers({
  days: function(){
    var arrayOfDates =[];
    // create your array based on the date range and interval you want
    return arrayOfDates;
  },
  documents: function(d){
    var start = Date(getFullYear(d),getMonth(d),getDate(d));
    var end = Date(getFullYear(d),getMonth(d),getDate(d)+1);
    return Documents.find({ date: { $gte: start, $lt: end }});
  }
});
```

See [javascript - get array of dates between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4413991/2805154)