# Javascript - get multiple date entries (2 times) between 2 days effieicenty

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario where I am trying to achieve the following:

I have the below variables:

```
StartDate = 16/02/2016
EndDate = 18/02/2016

StartTime 09:00:00
FinishTime 17:00:00
```

from this I am trying to make a function that can take the `StartDate` and `EndDate`, and store all the values within a multi-dimensional array. so the array would read:

```
     startDate                endDate
16/02/2016 09:00:00     16/02/2016 17:00:00    
17/02/2016 09:00:00     16/02/2016 17:00:00 
18/02/2016 09:00:00     16/02/2016 17:00:00
```

currently I am using 2 septate functions and 2 separate arrays to get a result however I dont feel this is good practice or efficient, but cannot think of a way of making this code better, please could you take a look at it and suggest anything better?

using `window.alert()` on the array is good enough for now :) thankyou for the help

the code (REVISED):

```
 function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
    var dateArray = new Array();
    var currentDate = startDate;
    while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
        dateArray.push(currentDate)
        currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
    }
    return dateArray;
}

Date.prototype.addDays = function (days) {
    var dat = new Date(this.valueOf())
    dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);

    return dat;
}

myapp.TestScreen.Test_execute = function (screen) {

    var sDate = new Date(screen.StartDate);
    var eDate = new Date(screen.EndDate);

    var nightCount = -1;
    var fullDateArray = [];

    var dateArray = getDates(sDate, eDate);
    for (i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {

        var tempSdate = new Date (dateArray[i])
        var tempEdate = new Date(dateArray[i])

        tempSdate.setHours(9);
        tempSdate.setMinutes(0);

        tempEdate.setHours(17);
        tempEdate.setMinutes(0);

        fullDateArray.push(tempSdate);
        fullDateArray.push(tempEdate);
        nightCount++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < fullDateArray.length; i++) {
        console.log(fullDateArray[i]);
    }
```

code above used from:
[javascript - get array of dates between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413590/javascript-get-array-of-dates-between-2-dates)

Comment: If code is working then question would be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ahh ok then, thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question moved to another forum as the code works, it just requires improvement