# how to get days between two dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 datepickers fr startdate and enddate.

1) For example, My startdate is "01/08/2016". And my end date is "06/08/2016".

2) I have selected (August 1 to august 6) total six days.

3) How can I get those days or print that all 6 days in a alert.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D9C4F/10/)

```js
var nowTemp = new Date();
      var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
      var checkin = jQuery('#startDate').fdatepicker({
          format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
          onRender: function (date) {
              return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
          }
      }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
          }).data('datepicker');
      var checkout = jQuery('#endDate').fdatepicker({
          format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
          onRender: function (date) {
              return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
          }
      }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
              checkout.hide();
          }).data('datepicker');

          jQuery("#startDate,#endDate").fdatepicker({
              autoclose: true,
              format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
              language: 'de',
              todayHighlight: false
          });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="startDate" name="start_datum" class="input_text date"   value="" >
    
<input type="text" id="endDate" name="end_datum" class="input_text" value="">
```

Comment: Does Date object [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript - get array of dates between 2 dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413590/javascript-get-array-of-dates-between-2-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Date.prototype.getDate` and `Date.prototype.setDate`:

```js
var start = new Date('2016-07-31'),
  end = new Date('2016-08-06');

var date = start;
do {
  var date = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1));
  console.log(date);
} while (date < end);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
var days = Math.round(Math.abs((date1.getTime() - date2.getTime())/(24*60*60*1000)));
```

Comment: It is just printing how many days... I want to print all the dates.

Comment: Use for statement that run "days" time and execute `date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + countDays)` where countDays is 1

Answer (score 0):

You could use moment js. See the solution with that library:

```
    var dateB = moment('2016-08-01');
    var dateC = moment('2016-08-06');

    console.log('Difference is ', dateB.diff(dateC), 'milliseconds');
    console.log('Difference is ', dateB.diff(dateC, 'days'), 'days');
```

This library is perfect for dates management.