# How to get dates array between two date time

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, node.js

I have a following date fields

```
{ tripScheduleStartDate: '2018-12-05T18:30:00.000Z',
  tripScheduleEndDate: '2018-12-07T18:30:00.000Z',
}
```

How can i get datetime array from start to end, something like this

```
[ { date: '2018-12-05T18:30:00.000Z' }, { date: '2018-12-06T18:30:00.000Z' },{ date: '2018-12-07T18:30:00.000Z' } ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - get array of dates between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413590/javascript-get-array-of-dates-between-2-dates)

Answer (score 1):

PSEUDO-CODE

```
Time start = x;
Time end = y
tmpTime = x;
timeArray = [];
While (tmpTime < y) {
timeArray.Add(tmpTime)
tmpTime = tmpTime.AddDays(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eachDay` from [`date-fns`](https://date-fns.org/docs/eachDay).

```
{ 
  tripScheduleStartDate: '2018-12-05T18:30:00.000Z',
  tripScheduleEndDate: '2018-12-07T18:30:00.000Z',
}
```

Import: `import eachDay from 'date-fns/each_day'`

Usage: `eachDay(tripScheduleStartDate, tripScheduleEndDate)`

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
        var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
        return date;
    }

    function gettheDates(sDate, eDate) {
        var dateArray = new Array();
        var ctDate = sDate;
        while (ctDate <= eDate) {
            dateArray.push(new Date (ctDate ));
            ctDate = ctDate .addDays(1);
        }
            return dateArray;
    }
```