# How to find dates between selected dates in angular 6?

Tags: typescript, date, angular6

I need  dates for between  selected 2 dates

 - I Have first date as **17-12-2018** and last date as **22-12-2018**

 - Need dates between in this two dates in angular 6.

 - I have searched but many results to find number of  days for the selected 2 dates.

Comment: Like, the number of days between the two dates? A simple search on SO or Google would help you find this.

Comment: I tried but everyone saying to find number of days only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - get array of dates between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413590/javascript-get-array-of-dates-between-2-dates)

Comment: actually before i did in javascript and php also... but i does not in angular

Comment: Angular uses typescript, and typescript compiles to JS. You can transform any JS code into typescript and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use momentjs and make sure to choose a valid date format

```
let a = moment(new Date('12-17-2018'));
let b = moment(new Date('12-22-2018'));
let tempDate = a;
let daysCount = b.diff(a, 'days');

console.log('daysCount',daysCount);

let dates:Array<Date> = [];

for(let i= 1;i<daysCount ;i++){
  tempDate =tempDate.add(1, 'day');
  dates.push(tempDate.toDate());
}

console.log(dates);
```

Comment: In this array it gives full date details.but i need only date alone

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a list of date objects corresponding to the dates in between those 2?
like {18-12-2018, 19-12-2018, 20-12-2018, 21-12-2018} ?

If so, you should write a function which takes two date objects and returns a list containing the dates in between them by (in a loop) creating a new date with the "day" value incremented, checking if that new date is earlier than the end date, if so, add it to your list. If not, exit the loop.