# Minutes per hour within date range in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

How do build an array with minute counts per hour within a set date range.

Assuming you have these dates

```
const start = new Date('2019-04-04 12:14');
const end = new Date('2019-04-04 16:21');
```

How do you turn that into and array looking like this:

```
const minutes_per_hour = [
    {
        hour: 12,
        minute_count: 46
    },
    {
        hour: 13,
        minute_count: 60
    },
    {
        hour: 14,
        minute_count: 60
    },
    {
        hour: 15,
        minute_count: 60
    },
    {
        hour: 16,
        minute_count: 21
    }
];
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve the issue yourself? Also, it's not clear why "12:14" has a `minute_count` of 46 rather than 14...

Comment: There are two dates and 5 items in array.

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's a start date and time, so if you start at :14, theres 46 minutes left to fill the remaining timegap (until 13:00 in this case).

Comment: @Caramiriel that's a good clarification that should be incorporated in the question, no?

Comment: [This answer to a similar question should get you started](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4413687/215552).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple function that should do what you want. It works by repeatedly calculating the minutes until the next hour (or `end`, if that's closer) and  incrementing to the next hour, eventually stopping when `end` is reached.

```js
/**
 * Gets the minutes in each sequential hour in a time range
 * @param {Date} start
 * @param {Date} end
 * @return {{hour:number, minute_count:number}[]}
 */
function getMinutesPerHour(start, end) {
  const outp = [];
  let current = start;
  while (current < end) {
    const minutesToNextHour = 60 - current.getMinutes();
    const nextHour = new Date(+current + minutesToNextHour * 60 * 1000);
    const minutes = nextHour > end
      ? end.getMinutes() - current.getMinutes()
      : minutesToNextHour;
    outp.push({ hour: current.getHours(), minutes: minutes, });
    current = nextHour;
  }
  return outp;
}

console.log(getMinutesPerHour(new Date('2019-04-04 12:14'), new Date('2019-04-04 16:21')));
```