# Js Calculate every day between two dates

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting, date-parsing

We consider that I have the following dates:

```
from: 21/09/2019

to: 29/09/2019
```

The result I would like to have is such a thing:

```
[
  {
    "day": 21,
    "month": 9,
    "year": 2019
  },
  ...
  {
    "day": 29,
    "month": 9,
    "year": 2019
  }
]
```

If I had such a thing:

```
from: 21/09/2019

to: 7/10/2019
```

The result I would like to have is such a thing:

```
[
  {
    "day": 21,
    "month": 9,
    "year": 2019
  },
  ...
  {
    "day": 30,
    "month": 9,
    "year": 2019
  },
  ...
  {
    "day": 1,
    "month": 10,
    "year": 2019
  }
  {
    "day": 7,
    "month": 10,
    "year": 2019
  }
]
```

What I would like to do is print in an array, all the days between the start date and the end date.

I was trying something like this, but I'm having some problems:

```
let from = "23/09/2019";
let to = "7/10/2019";

function getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

function calculate(from, to) {
  let splitF = from.split("/");
  let splitT = to.split("/");
  let array = [];

  let dF = parseInt(splitF[0]);
  let dT = parseInt(splitT[0]);
  let mF = parseInt(splitF[1]);
  let mT = parseInt(splitT[1]);
  let yF = parseInt(splitF[2]);
  let yT = parseInt(splitT[2]);

  let day, init, final;

  while (true) {
    if (mF === mT && yF === yT) {
      day = dT - dF;
    } else {
      day = getDaysInMonth(mF, yF)-dF;
    }
    init = dF;
    final = init + day;
    Array.apply(null, { length: final + 1 })
      .map(Number.call, Number)
      .slice(init)
      .reduce((prev, curr) => {
        let obj = {
          day: curr,
          month: mF,
          year: yF
        };
        array.push(obj);
        return prev;
      }, []);
    if (mF === mT && yF === yT) break;
    mF++;
    dF = 1;
    if (mF === 13) {
      mF = 1;
      yF++;
    }
  }
  return array;
}

console.log(calculate(from, to));
```

Comment: did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413590/javascript-get-array-of-dates-between-2-dates)? When you say problems, can you describe the problems you are having?

Comment: This is 3 questions in one (parse, add 1 day, format), which have all been answered many, many times before.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to extract the numeical "parts" of your input date strings `from` and `to` by spliting against `/` characters:

```
// Obtain day, month, year integers of the "from" date string
const [fromDay, fromMonth, fromYear] = from.split("/").map(part => Number.parseInt(part));
```

Once you have these date parts as integers, the date range can be iterated through a for-loop where, per iteration, you add an item object to the `result` array based on the current iteration of that loop:

```
// Add an item object with date number for current iteration
result.push({ day, month, year });
```

Per iteration, you'd also check to see if the next date be iterated is equal to the number "parts" of the `to` date (as well as incrementing the current month and year as needed):

```js
const numDaysInMonth = (month, year) => new Date(year, month, 0).getDate()
const extractParts = (date) => date.split("/").map(part => Number.parseInt(part));

const calcDaysBetweenDates = (from, to) => {

  const [fromDay, fromMonth, fromYear] = extractParts(from);
  const [toDay, toMonth, toYear] = extractParts(to);
  const result = [];

  // Iterate over from-to range starting at from year/month/day
  for (let year = fromYear, month = fromMonth, day = fromDay;;) {

    // Add item object for current day/month/year to result array
    result.push({
      day,
      month,
      year
    });

    // Increment day
    day++;

    // If next day past current month, reset day, increment month
    if (day > numDaysInMonth(month, year)) {
      month++;
      day = 1;
    }

    // If next month past current year, reset month, increment year
    if (month > 12) {
      month = 1;
      year++;
    }

    // If next day and month and year past to day/month/year, exit loop
    if (day >= toDay && month >= toMonth && year >= toYear) {
      break;
    }
  }

  // Add to date for range inclusivity 
  result.push({
    day: toDay,
    month: toMonth,
    year: toYear
  });

  return result;
}

console.log(calcDaysBetweenDates("21/09/2019", "29/09/2019"));
console.log(calcDaysBetweenDates("21/09/2019", "7/10/2019"));
console.log(calcDaysBetweenDates("25/12/2019", "5/1/2020"));
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your script, with the second date: "09/21/2019", "7/10/2019"
It also gives me 09/31/2019, but this date does not exist.

Comment: @Paul sorry about that, was calculating the number of days for the next month rather than the current. Just updated script - does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can add date by 1 to start date and Date object will take care of validating the new date ie next month or next year and all, repeat till end date `toDate` is greater than start date `fromDate`.

```js
let from = "23/09/2019";
let to = "29/10/2019";

// convert to date object by interchanging date/month expected by Date function
let fromDate = new Date(from.replace(/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)/,'$2/$1'));
let toDate = new Date(to.replace(/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)/,'$2/$1'));

let response = [];
while(toDate > fromDate){
  response.push({day: fromDate.getDate(), month: fromDate.getMonth()+1, year: fromDate.getFullYear()});
  fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate()+1) // increment date by 1
}

console.log(response)
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your script, if you see the return value from the console, the values start from the date: 08/24/2019, but the date you make it starts from 09/23/2019.

Comment: month is a 0 indexed array. I updated the answer

Comment: If I wanted to include even the first day and not exclude it?

Comment: you definitely can, increment after pushing to array. Check updated answer

Comment: did it work for you?

Answer (score -1):

You could use [moment](https://momentjs.com/) together with [moment range](https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range).

```js
window['moment-range'].extendMoment(moment);

const start = moment('21/09/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
const end = moment('29/09/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY');

const range = moment.range(start, end);

for (let pt of range.by('day')) {
 console.log(pt.format('DD/MM/YYYY'))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-range/4.0.2/moment-range.js"></script>
```