# How to get all the dates within a date range in ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I currently have a start date (2019-11-30) and a end date (2019-12-7). How do I list out all the dates in between and put them into an array?

I want to store it in this format in the array:

```
["2019-11-30", "2019-11-31", "2019-12-1", "2019-12-2", "2019-12-3", "2019-12-4", "2019-11-5"];
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15882220/6509848 Probably need to use momentjs

Comment: @AthifShaffy Are there any other ways to do it without momentjs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50398144/6509848 you can follow this

Comment: @AthifShaffy I keep getting errors. Is there any example codes that I can follow and also see the outcome?

Comment: Yeah will post as answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple example that maybe work for you:

```
var startDate = new Date("2019-11-30"); //YYYY-MM-DD
var endDate = new Date("2019-12-07"); //YYYY-MM-DD


function formatDate(date) {

  var day = date.getDate();
  var month = date.getMonth()+1;
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  return day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
}

var getDateArray = function(start, end) {
    var arr = new Array();
    var dt = new Date(start);
    while (dt <= end) {
        arr.push(formatDate(new Date(dt)));
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return arr;
}

var dateArr = getDateArray(startDate, endDate);

console.log(dateArr)
```

I hope this will help you