# How to get the full dates between two dates using javascript / react?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, date

My requirement is to get the number of days between two dates.

For example, the start date is `02/20/2020` to `01/03/2020` I would like to display the results like

> Feb 20 Thursday, Feb 21 Friday,....01 Mar Monday.

I went through this scenario in StackOverflow but I didn't get the expected solution for the same.

Could anyone please guide in achieving this scenario using javascript or react?

Comment: I've reopened this as OP wants to print the full dates between the start and end date. The duplicate target only showed how to get the number of days between two dates, not how to print each of them.

Comment: @John_ny https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413590/javascript-get-array-of-dates-between-2-dates this will help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may calculate the difference between dates, than make up desired array of dates casted to date string of necessary format:

```js
const d1 = new Date('02/20/2020'),
      d2 = new Date('03/01/2020'),
      diff = (d2-d1)/864e5,
      dateFormat = {weekday:'long',month:'short',day:'numeric'},
      dates = Array.from(
        {length: diff+1},
        (_,i) => {
          const date = new Date() 
          date.setDate(d1.getDate()+i) 
          const [weekdayStr, dateStr] = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US',dateFormat).split(', ')
          return `${dateStr} ${weekdayStr}`
        }
      )
      
console.log(dates)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%;}
```

Or, as long as we're having fun here :) following is React implementation:

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM,
      { useState } = React
      
const DatePicker = ({min,max,onPick,role}) => (
  <input 
    type="date" 
    onChange={onPick}
    {...{min,max}}
  />
)  

const ListOfDates = ({startDate,endDate}) => {
    const d1 = new Date(startDate),
          d2 = new Date(endDate),
          diff = (d2-d1)/864e5,
          dateFormat = {weekday:'long',month:'short',day:'numeric'},
          dates = Array.from(
            {length: diff+1},
            (_,i) => {
              const date = new Date() 
              date.setDate(d1.getDate()+i) 
              const [weekdayStr, dateStr] = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US',dateFormat).split(', ')
              return `${dateStr} ${weekdayStr}`
            }
          )
     return (
        <ul>
          {dates.map((date,key) => <li {...{key}}>{date}</li>)}
        </ul>
     )
}

const App = () => {
  const [start, setStart] = useState(''),
        [end, setEnd] = useState(''),
        onPickStart = ({target:{value}}) => setStart(value),
        onPickEnd = ({target:{value}}) => setEnd(value)
  return (
    <div>
      <DatePicker max={end} onPick={onPickStart} />
      <DatePicker min={start} onPick={onPickEnd} />
      <ListOfDates startDate={start} endDate={end} />
    </div>
  )
        
}

render (
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

...and jQuery one:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('.datepick').on('change', function(){
    $(this).attr('id') == 'startDate' ?
    $('#endDate').attr('min', $(this).val()) :
    $('#startDate').attr('max', $(this).val())
    if($('#startDate').length && $('#endDate').length) {
      const d1 = new Date($('#startDate').val()),
            d2 = new Date($('#endDate').val()),
            diff = (d2-d1)/864e5,
            dateFormat = {weekday:'long',month:'short',day:'numeric'},
            dates = Array.from(
              {length: diff+1},
              (_,i) => {
                const date = new Date() 
                date.setDate(d1.getDate()+i) 
                const [weekdayStr, dateStr] = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US',dateFormat).split(', ')
                return `${dateStr} ${weekdayStr}`
              }
            ),
            dateListItems = dates.map(d => `<li>${d}</li>`)
      $('#dateList').html(dateListItems)
    }
  })
        
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Start Date: <input id="startDate" type="date" class="datepick"></input></label>
<label>End Date: <input id="endDate" type="date" class="datepick"></input></label>
<ul id="dateList"></ul>
```

Comment: i would to get the days for repestive dates as well.

Comment: Having fun? :-D

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov oh, well I think I submitted my answer like 1 minute after yours and so, yes, since OP asked about js or react, I thought I'd do something slightly different. :)

Answer (score 4):

you can use `momentjs` to get the result:

```
//let moment = require("moment");

let date = [];

let startDate = "02/20/2020";
let endDate = "01/03/2020";
while ( moment(startDate, "MM/DD/YYYY").valueOf() <= moment(endDate, "DD/MM/YYYY").valueOf()) {
  date.push(moment(startDate, "MM/DD/YYYY").format("MMM DD dddd"));
  startDate = moment(startDate, "MM/DD/YYYY").add(1, "days").format("MM/DD/YYYY");
}
console.log(date);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start by first creating two date objects, one for the start date and another for the end date. Then, find out how many days are in between these dates. Finally, you can loop through this number and get the current date plus the current index in the loop and print that.

As a React component:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [dates, setDates] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const start = new Date('02/20/2020');
    const end = new Date('03/01/2020');

    const daysBetween = (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
    const arr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i <= daysBetween; i++) {
      const temp = new Date();
      temp.setDate(start.getDate() + i)
      arr.push(temp);
    }
    
    setDates(arr);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <ul>
      {dates.map(date => (
        <li key={date}>
          {date.toLocaleDateString(
            "en-US",
            {month: "short", day: "2-digit", weekday: "long"}
          )}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method to get the difference between two dates in JavaScript:

```
const d1 = new Date("06/30/2019"); 
const d2 = new Date("07/30/2019"); 

// To calculate the time difference of two dates 
const timeDiff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime(); 

// To calculate the no. of days between two dates 
const days = timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24); 

//to list the days
while (days !== 0) {
    let date = new Date(d2)
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - days)
    console.log(date)
    days--
}
```

Comment: Your answer does ***not*** deliver expected result (array of date strings adjusted accordingly to OP's format). Besides you may achieve above result subtracting `date2` and `date1` directly (without `.getTime()`) and `1000*3600*24=864e5`, for short

Answer (score 0):

From the date given, find the difference in days then based on the no of days, make a loop and log each increment day in between using `toLocaleString()`..

```js
const startDate = "02/20/2020";
const endDate = "03/01/2020";

const diffTime = Math.abs(new Date(endDate) - new Date(startDate));
const diffDays = 0|diffTime/864e5; 


for(let i = 0; i <= diffDays; i++){
  const newdate = new Date(new Date(startDate).getTime()+(i*864e5));
  console.log(newdate.toLocaleString('en-us', { day:'2-digit', month: 'short', weekday:'long'}))
}
```

Comment: There's no need for `Math.ceil()` (which can be done as `const diffDays = 0|diffTime/864e5`, as long as your attempt was to post *shorter* way), since resulting timestamps would be divisible by (1000*60*60*24, by default)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov, Thanks for pointing out, have updated answer..

Comment: You're most welcome, there's another move you can make - your date string format is *somewhat* different from requested (refer to OP for details).

Comment: And, by the way, you can make `(i*24*60*60*1000)` shorter in the same way: `i*864e5`