# split all date from start date & end date in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

i am trying to split date in mongodb. For Example ,start date is 2020-07-01  & end date is 2020-07-05 , then , all date should be split in a sequence (i.e:- 2020-07-01,2020-07-02,2020-07-03,2020-07-04,2020-07-05) ?can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the date array in JS, Using MomentJS preferrably

[Javascript - get array of dates between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413590/javascript-get-array-of-dates-between-2-dates)

Answer (score 0):

in js, you could

```js
var start = new Date("2020-03-05");
var stop = new Date("2020-03-09");

for (d=start; d<=stop; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
  console.log(d)
 }
```

Comment: Great - if this was useful, mark the answer as correct for other users