# get all date between 2 different date in new Date vue.js

Tags: javascript, date

how can I get each date between the **date1** and **date2**

```js
var date1 = new Date("06/30/2019");
var date2 = new Date("07/30/2019");

var Difference_In_Time = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

var Difference_In_Days = Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24);

//To display the final no. of days (result) 
document.write("Total number of days between dates  <br>" +
  date1 + "<br> and <br>" +
  date2 + " is: <br> " +
  Difference_In_Days);
```

Comment: I'd start by using a better `Date` constructor, eg `new Date(2019, 5, 30)`. See the big warning here ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Timestamp_string

Comment: Your code appears to be _working_ (though it may struggle with daylight-savings change over times) so what's the problem?

Comment: Do you want to collect dates inclusive of `date1` and `date2`?

Comment: [*Javascript - get array of dates between 2 dates*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413590/javascript-get-array-of-dates-between-2-dates) seems to answer the question. What part of this is specific to vue.js?

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, then you need to use a for-loop
and if you wanna display it in vue, then you'd use v-for directive
here is an example of how the code looks like

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p v-for="day in days" :key="days.indexOf(day)">{{day}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "App",
    components: {},
    data() {
      return {
        days: []
      };
    },
    created() {
      var date1 = new Date("06/30/2019");
      var date2 = new Date("07/30/2019");
      var Difference_In_Time = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
      var Difference_In_Days = Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
      for (var i = 0; i < Difference_In_Days; i++) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setDate(date1.getDate() + i + 1);
        this.days.push(d);
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: please explain your answer with code

Comment: @sonEtLumiere, I have added the app code, hope it's helpful