# JQuery syntax confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am almost new to JQuery. So please forgive if it is trivial.

What does this mean in JQuery: var Utilities = $([]);

Is this like defining an array? Any links to an example?

Some more info: After defining that in the code I see:

```
Utilities.Message = ' some message';
Utilities.function1 = function(message) { some code };
Utilities.function2 = function() { some code};
```

calling the method: Utilities.function2();

Thanks,
-Sara.

Comment: That appears that they are just creating a jQuery selector with no elements selected. jQuery selectors are simply an array of DOM elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$([])` would use the [`jQuery( elementArray )` signature](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) to create an empty `jQuery` collection.

The `jQuery()` signature, that now does the same, wasn't available until jQuery 1.4, so `jQuery([])` could be used before that and can still be used to be compatible with older versions of the library.

Prior to 1.4, `jQuery()` would do the same as `jQuery(document)`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that means anything. I don't believe you can ave an array as a selector like that.

Defining an array would be:

var Utilities.Urls = [];

This has some good info: [defining array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047582/defining-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you. Actually I am reviewing my a senior person's code. So this should be correct. I will elaborate more on the question.