# Is this a scope issue or am I setting up my array of objects incorrectly?

Tags: javascript

I am having some problems with two objects in my javascript code.

My first object is from an API call which I haven't listed here, but the `data` variable being passed into my `getStudentStats()` function is the result of that API call and its output can be seen in the image below highlighted **[1]**. It is a list of students and their associated data.

My second object is the result of a JSON call which can be seen below (the `UWA.Data.getJson()` function). Its output can be seen in the image below highlighted **[2]**. It is a list of students' IDs and some statistics from my local database, i.e. the number of flags they've received and the number of interventions that have been raised for them.

```
getStudentStats : function(data) {

    /* [1] Console log */
    console.log(data);

    var student_list = '';

    for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ )
        student_list += data[i].id + ',';

    student_list = student_list.substring(0, student_list.length - 1);

    var Students = [];
    var Student_Data = data;

    UWA.Data.getJson(FLAGS_Assign_Flags.url + 'get_students_stats&arg=' + student_list, function(data) {
        /* [2] Console log */
        console.log(data);

        for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
            var Student_ID = data[i].Student_ID;
            var obj = { 'flags': data[i].Flags, 'interventions': data[i].Interventions };
            Students[Student_ID] = obj;
        }

        /* [3] Console log */
        console.log(Students);

        FLAGS_Assign_Flags.displayStudents(Students, Student_Data);
    });

},
```

What I'm trying to do is, basically, display some information from both of these objects (using jQuery `.html()` and a string variable).

```
displayStudents : function(students, data) {

    /* Set up our HTML variable which we'll .html() when it's populated */
    var StudentsHTML = '<ul id="students_display">';

    for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
        /* For each student in the `data` object, grab their ID to access the correct element in the students object */
        var id = data[i].id;

        /* Set up a variable which we'll use to display the students' stats in our LI */
        var stats = '<div>';

        /* If the student doesn't have any flags or interventions, manually set the text */
        if( typeof students[id] != 'undefined' )
            stats += ' (F:<span class="f">' + students[id].Flags + '</span>|I:<span class="i">' + students[id].Flags + '</span>)';
        else
            stats += ' (F:<span class="f">0</span>|I:<span class="i">0</span>)'; 

        stats += '</div>';

        /* Produce checkbox, name and stats for each student and add them to the HTML variable */
        StudentsHTML += '<li><input type="checkbox" name="students" value="' + data[i].id + '" />&nbsp;' + data[i].firstname + ' ' + data[i].surname + stats + '</li>';
    }

    StudentsHTML += '</ul>';

    /* Set the HTML... */
    $('#students').html(StudentsHTML);

    /* Do some other stuff not relevant to this question! */
    FLAGS_Assign_Flags.displayForm();

},
```

The problem is, as you can see in the image below highlighted **[3]**, my `Students` object appears as a load of garbage in console and I can't access any information from it.

[image: Scope or object]

Is this a scope issue, or am I setting up my array of objects incorrectly?

Comment: Can you verify that `var Student_ID = data[i].Student_ID;` is giving you the value that you expect?  Let's pinpoint where the `undefined` is actually happening to help determine the root cause.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I knew I should've added that - it definitely is. If I add `console.log(Student_ID);` directly after the line you quoted my script correctly logs the students' IDs.

Comment: Looks like it is definitely how the array is defined.  Take a look here at this [question about array declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6047582/475820).  It might help you get it figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created `var Students = [];` as an array, and are later using it as an associative array to assign values to it:

```
Students[Student_ID] = obj;
```

This will not work, you should create the Students var as an object:

```
var Students = {};
```

Javascript does not have a notion of 'associative arrays', and you should use basic objects for this purpose.

Later on, you can loop through these with `for in`, too safely use `for in`, combine it with a [call to hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
for (var i in Students) {
    if (!Students.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue; // skip inherited properties
    // i == StudentID
    // Students[i] == your student object
}
```

Comment: Ahh.. I think we're on the right lines here Nicky. When I change my code to use the Object type instead of an Array as per your suggestion, I can now actually `console.log` the `Students` object. *However*, I was trying to create an *Array of Objects* so that I could, in the second function, access my students' statistics using something like `students[123456].Flags` (or `students[id_variable].Flags` more likely). With your code I'm unsure as to whether I can do that?

Comment: Scrap that Nicky, you can! Thanks :)

Comment: yes, you can. Javascript objects can be accessed with array operators: `Students.123456 == Students['123456']`

Comment: Aye. After changing my code to reflect your solution it didn't work. Then I quickly realised that I was trying to access the object's keys using the wrong case (should've been `flags` not `Flags`). Whoops! Working now, have accepted.

Answer (score 2):

```
Students[Student_ID] = obj;
```

Is probably the problem.

For example:

```
var arr = [];
arr[4] = {};
=>
[undefined × 4, Object]
```

Comment: I don't follow fully I'm afraid. What would you suggest as a solution?

Comment: Students.push(obj); And add the id of the student to obj then if you want to retrive a student from the array by id, make a search function (or use underscore.js).