# Multiple variable declaration using loop javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, object

I was trying to create an array which contains 3 fixed fields.
So, something like

```
var x0 = new Array(x,y,z);
```

Now the thing is there can be multiple arrays like x[], which have the different values.
So something like

```
   var x1 = new Array(x,y,z); x2 = new Array(x,y,z);
```

I would be passing values to the variables x,y,z like x0[0] = "test", x0[1] = "another",...
I need to create a variable number of such arrays, so say if i pass a value say 10, it should create 10 different arrays for me. How does one do this, is it allowed to use a loop for creating variables?

There is something called as multi dimensional array, but I wasn't sure of how to use it. I tried but apparently it is very different and I did not understand it.
Also, I thought of declaring an object, and passing values to it's parameters, and create objects as needed. Is this possible? And which method will be better?

Is there any other way of doing this? maybe something which would be most efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an array of arrays:

```
var myArrays = [];

for(var i=0;i<something;i++){
    myArrays.push([x,y,z]);
}
```

Then, instead of `x0[0]` you would have `x[0][0]`.

Note, you shouldn't use `new Array` but instead use `[]`.

Comment: Ok, i just tried this.
`var myArrays = [];
var x= "a"; var y="b"; var z="c";
for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
    myArrays.push([x,y,z]);
}`

I get x[0][0] as a, which is good. but x[0][1] gives undefined. How do i get b?

Comment: Works for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/6YjHX/  `x` is just "a", the arrays is `myArrays`, so `myArrays[0][1]`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean

```
var x  =[];
x[0]=["x","y","z"];
x[1]=["x","y","z"];
x[2]=["x","y","z"];
```

or

```
function addArr(arr,newarr) {
  arr[arr.length]=newarr; // or arr.push(newarr);
}
var x  =[];
for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
  addArr(x,[i,i+1,i+2]);
}
```

Comment: The second answer looks what i wanted. Will try it.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var n = 100; // number of x-arrays (x0, x1, ...)
var allX = new Array(n); // array of length n

for (var i=0; i<n; i++){
   allX[i] = [x,y,z]; // array with elements x, y, z
}
```

now you can access e.g. the second array (`x1`) like:

```
var x1 = allX[1];
```

or the third element of the third array (`x2[2]`) like:

```
var z = allX[2][2];
```

**Edit**: see [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/whats-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-arr/1273936#1273936) about the differences of array declaration between `new Array()` and `[]`

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little naive, but it looks like this should solve it.
Thanks for the detail on how to use it :)

Comment: You're welcome! Just because you are new here: don't forget to accept an answer and upvote whichever you liked! Good luck with your code.

Comment: @mplungjan : I checked out the differences. I now let the first declaration use the known number of elements by 'new Array(n)' because it is often [fastest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/whats-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-arr/3132371#3132371). The elements of sub-arrays are known, rather than the number of elements, so no need to call the Array-constructor and '[]' will be [fastest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/whats-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-arr/1273936#1273936) and is more readable. Goed zo?

Comment: Please read the complete post and links in the first link you posted.

Comment: I did (again), and continue to understand that `new Array(..)` can be fastest if you know the number of elements beforehand; otherwise `[]` should be used. What am I seeing wrong here?