# declaring more than 10 objects

Tags: javascript

as we know we can declare an array like this

```
for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++)

{ d[i]=new array();}
```

What about an object I want to declare more than 10 objects and I think it's not efficient to 
write a declare statements for 10 times !!like this

```
car c1 = new car();
car c2= new Car();
```

..etc

what can I do ?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have explicit data types...

Comment: I'm assuming your `car c1` and `car c2` were meant to be `var c1` and `var c2`

Comment: Also I'm assuming that with `new car()` and `new Car()` you meant `new Car()` for both, JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming by `int i` you meant `var i`

Comment: Mmmm I want to ask car seller  to insert Car Info. then save it in a linkedlist 
this linkedlist's elements are  objects from Car class 
So can I declare more than 1 object according to seller numbers of cars !!?

Answer (score 6):

You are mixing the things a little.

```
var array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    array[i] = new Car();
}
```

As Daniel noted, you can even use Array.push() in this way:

```
var array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    array.push(new Car());
}
```

The point is that you declare the array with `var array = []` (or with `var array = new Array()`, see the differences here [What’s the difference between "Array()" and "[]" while declaring a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/whats-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-arr)) and you set the items at the index you want (in Javascript arrays are dynamicly sized)

Comment: +1. If you are accumulating a collection of cars like this, it's better to use an array than 10 independent variables.

Comment: @HansEngel It depends on the language though. I once heared from a flash developer that in Flash writing 1 statement 10 times is faster then using a loop.

Comment: `int i`? Wasn't aware Javascript had `int`

Comment: @vol7ron Int? you see ints? I don't see ints :-)

Comment: @vol7ron No C#, and every time I write JS I have to correct all my `int` and `string` :-) At least the `{}` and the `[]` gets correctly.

Comment: @vol7ron And I'll add that the proposal for [ECMAScript 4.0](http://www.ecmascript.org/es4/spec/overview.pdf) HAD strongly typed variables. But it was like `var p : int`.

Answer (score 3):

Use an array of objects like:

```
var cars = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cars.push(new Car());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hum, what you're doing in your first example is declaring an array of array. To create an array, simply do

```
var a = [];
```

To create and maintain many objects, put them in that array:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    a[i] = new Car();

car[0].drive(); //Drive first car
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. use `eval` (it was designed for things like this)
2. use an array of objects

---

1. ```
   for (var i=1,n=3; i<n; i++)
      eval("c" + i + "= new Car()");
   ```
2. ```
   var a = [];
   for (var i=1,n=3; i<n; i++)
      a[i] = new Car();
   ```

Comment: How was `eval` designed for things like this?

Comment: @Xeon06: eval was created to run dynamically generated code, which should not depend on the client input/values.  If you want a particular set of variables, that follow a name scheme, but want to condense your code, you'd use `eval` (See the example).

Comment: Well I'd still rather use an array for numbered variable names like that, but I can see where this might be useful.

Comment: Me too, but this wasn't about our choice, I was answering the OPs question :)