# JQuery how to make list from textbox values

Tags: jquery

I have following textbox

```
input name="txt_Exam" id="txt_Exam" type="Text"
input name="txt_PassingYear" id="txt_PassingYear" type="Text"
input name="txt_school" id="txt_school" type="Text"
input name="txt_university" id="txt_university" type="Text"
input name="txt_board" id="txt_board" type="Text"
input name="txt_percentage" id="txt_percentage" type="Text"
input type="button" onclick="makeList"
```

When I click the button, what all are I entre in the above text box, that all values are arranged as a table and it show in one div like this .

```
SSLC  2008 XXXX -     STATE 80  edit remove
HSC   2010 -    XXXX  STATE 84  edit remove
```

and remove or edit this row if i need

Comment: @Selva Kumar K.P. Please provide more details

Comment: Still i have not get any answer

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var arr= new Array();
arr.push($('#txt_Exam').text());
```

when all value are pushed , rebind your result in your `Div` format.

Comment: arrays should be created using `var arr = [];` -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/whats-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar/1273936#1273936

Comment: Here text box name and ids are comes from dynamically,some times text box count also differ.

Comment: But I have count how many text box will appear here, if there is any possible to apply class name for all text boxes and we select values based on class name and then make list