# Array within array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to make an array within an array.

It would contain some enemies with all different positions. I tried writing it like this:

```
var enemies = [
    position = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }
];
enemies.length = 6;
```

This seem to work, however, I don’t know what to write when I want to call it. `enemies[1].position.x` doesn’t work at all. Any leads?

Comment: Your first element would be enemies[0]

Comment: Your “array” is invalid syntax.

Comment: `var enemies = [{x:0, y:0}, {x:5, y:5}, {x:10, y:10}];` then just refer to `enemies[index].x`

Comment: @Xufox How is that? Though it's not very common or recommended, it's valid syntax.

Comment: @Xufox It's not invalid, he's just creating a global (`position`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Array inside Array - how can i call child array name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871634/javascript-array-inside-array-how-can-i-call-child-array-name)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want an array of enemy objects instead. Something like:

```
var enemies = [
    { position: { x: 0, y: 0 } },
    { position: { x: 0, y: 0 } },
    { position: { x: 0, y: 0 } }
];

var firstEnemy = enemies[0];

firstEnemy.position.x; // 0

var totalEnemies = enemies.length; // 3
```

Comment: Thanks, @nikhil. Completely missed that.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is

```
var enemies =  [
    {
        position: { x: 0, y: 0 }
    }
];

enemies[0].position.x;
```

Arrays index starts from `0`

Also, let's deconstruct why your code doesn't throw an error, and what it exactly does.

You are declaring an array named `enemies`, and when declaring it you are defining a global variable named `position` (and its value is returned)

After execution, `enemies` look like this `[ {x: 0, y: 0} ]`