# array inside another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

**Problem Statement**

I'm trying to create an array with another array inside this array, but it doesn't work for me.

**This is what i wrote:**

```
var arr = '{"project":['
                    + '{"id":"01","name":"project1","activity":['
                    + '{"num":"001","time":"7","desc":"desc","stam":['
                    + ' "pre":"005","pre2":"002"]}'
                    + '{"num":"002","time":"6","desc":"desc"}'
                    + '{"num":"003","time":"5","desc":"desc"}'
                    + '{"num":"004","time":"4","desc":"desc"}'
                    + '{"num":"005","time":"3","desc":"desc"}]}]}';
```

Comment: this may be useful, i am new to js so not sure if its of any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871634/javascript-array-inside-array-how-can-i-call-child-array-name

Comment: Don't try to build JSON by smashing strings together. It is simply too painful to debug. Use real arrays and real objects and once you are done, use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: That said, your trivial typo is revealed if you take the resulting string and paste it into http://jsonlint.com/ (voting to close because the problem was caused by a simple typographical error).

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON looks corrupted. You can use several online editors and validators to verify the JSON string. [editor](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) and [validator](http://jsonlint.com/) just as an example of mony others. You also might have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/de/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php).

- `,` is missing between the array elements
- the property `stam` looks more like an object than an array

It should look like this:

```
{"project":[
            {"id":"01","name":"project1","activity":
              [
                {"num":"001","time":"7","desc":"desc","stam":{
                  "pre":"005",
                  "pre2":"002"
                }
                },
                {"num":"002","time":"6","desc":"desc"},
                {"num":"003","time":"5","desc":"desc"},
                {"num":"004","time":"4","desc":"desc"},
                {"num":"005","time":"3","desc":"desc"}
              ]
            }
          ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The json is not formatted correctly:

```js
{
  project : [{
    id : "01",
    name: "project1", 
    activity :[
      { 
        num : "001",
        time : "7",
        desc : "desc",
        stam : [{
          pre : "005", 
          pre2: "002"
        }]
      },
      {
        num : "002", 
        time: "6",
        desc: "desc"
      },
      {
        num : "003",
        time: "5",
        desc:"desc"
      },
      {
        num : "004",
        time: "4",
        desc: "desc"
      },
      {
        num : "005",
        time: "3",
        desc: "desc"
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```