# About the definition of javascript variable

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between “Array()” and “[]” while declaring a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/whats-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar)

```
var all = [];
var all = new Array();
```

What is the difference between these two definitions? I can't make them clear.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. But best practice is to avoid using `new` on JavaScript primitive types.

Comment: There *is* a difference, please read the linked question.

Comment: For example: var all =[]; var all1= new Array(); the all1[2] may have undefined type, but variable all is always blank string, is it?