# How can I make an empty string array in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to have an array that holds string error messages. Here's the code that I came up with:

```
var errors: [string];
errors = [];
Object.keys(response.data.modelState).forEach(function (key) {
    errors.push.apply(errors, response.data.modelState[key]);
});
```

I tried some different ways to add a typescript definition to the variable errors but none seem to work for this case. The first definition works okay but then when I am pushing values I need to push to an array and when I set:

```
errors = [];
```

Then it gives me an error message:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  TS2322  Type
>   'undefined[]' is not assignable to type '[string]'.   Property '0' is
>   missing in type 'undefined[]'.
>   Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error      Build: Type
>   'undefined[]' is not assignable to type '[string]'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: Creating an empty typed container array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826745/typescript-creating-an-empty-typed-container-array)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The definition of **string array** should be:

```
// instead of this
// var errors: [string];
// we need this
var errors: string[];
errors = [];
```

**Note:** another issue could be the parameter key here

```
...forEach(function (key) {...
```

I would guess that we often should declare two of them, because first is very often value, second key/index

```
Object.keys(response.data.modelState)
      .forEach(function (value, key) {
    errors.push.apply(errors, response.data.modelState[key]);
});
```

And even, we should use arrow function, to get the parent as **`this`**

```
Object.keys(response.data.modelState)
      .forEach( (value, key) => {
    errors.push.apply(errors, response.data.modelState[key]);
});
```

Answer (score 17):

Missing an obvious answer, needed when not assigning it to a variable: `[] as string[]`

Answer (score 16):

Outside of a method:

```
arr: string[] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to set the `length` to `0`:

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4]
myArray.length = 0
```

This makes it possible to use `const` in contexts where emptying the array is needed.