# Redux reducer initial state with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I would like to create a reducer with typescript!

**paymentReducer.tsx**

```
let initialState = {
    saved: [],
};

export interface Payment {
    saved: ISavedPayment[];
}

export let payment = (
    state = initialState,
    { type, payload }: PaymentActions
): Payment => {
    switch (type) {
        case SAVED_PAYMENTS_LOADED:
            return { ...state, saved: payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

No errors! But the type of `saved` array in `state` parameter of reducer becomes `never`. But it should be `ISavedPayment[]`?

> `(parameter) state: { saved: never[]; }`

Comment: Why don't you specify the type explicitly?

Comment: Could you add any code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the type of initialState explicitly:

```
const initialState: { saved: ISavedPayment[] } = {
    saved: [],
};
```

See also:

- [What is "not assignable to parameter of type never" error in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423842/what-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-never-error-in-typescript)
- [TypeScript: Creating an empty typed container array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826745/typescript-creating-an-empty-typed-container-array)
- [[] is regard wrong as never[] when strictNullChecks is true #13140](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13140)