# How to declare an empty array type that is inside a JSON file?

Tags: typescript

I have this line of code that makes Typescript fire off an error:

```
const owner:boolean = jsonFile.owners.includes("10");
```

jsonFile is what I did from

```js
import * as jsonFile from './dir/to/json/file.json'
```

Owners is an empty `string[]`.

This is the error:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

I know that I need to assign the type to this array, e.g. make it `never[]` -> `string[]`, how would I do that? Preferably without `strictNullChecks` under tsconfig (solves this problem)

Comment: If you want to get the most out of a JSON object in typescript, I'd suggest making an interface for what you expect the JSON object to be (e.g. `interface JSONFile { owners: string[] }`) then casting the imported object to that type.

Comment: There's the option of using a [type assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826745/typescript-creating-an-empty-typed-container-array), but for JSON there might be a better solution.

Comment: Hmm. I ended up having to force myself to use this snippet of code: `const config:config = require('./config.json');` and I did use an interface (worked). This is what you mean by "casting the imported object to that type."?