# Javascript Array defined in constructor is undefined in prototype

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to writing OO JS, but this has stumped me. So I setup me new Call object, then define what I assume to be empty arrays. When I call AddFieldQueryToArray() I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
```

On `this.fieldArray.push(field)`

I don't really know why. I've tried `this.fieldArray = fieldArray;` in the constructor too.

```
    function Call() 
    {    
         var fieldArray = new Array();
         var queryArray = new Array();
    }

    Call.prototype.AddFieldQuerysToArray = function(field,query)
    {
        if(field !== 'undefined')
        {               
            this.fieldArray.push(field);
        }

        this.queryArray.push(query);

    }
```

Comment: Just one comment, in JavaScript pls always put opening braces on the same line of the statement: i.e. `function call() {`, `if (field !== 'undefined') {`. This has side effects in some cases such as with `return` and a proper JS code should keep this form.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should reference instance properties with `this.` inside the constructor:

```
function Call() 
{    
     this.fieldArray = [];
     this.queryArray = [];
}
```

*`new Array()` has a shortcut `[]` which I have used above.*

If you use `var fieldArray = [];` you would create a local variable which is destroyed once your instance has been created unless you use this kind of construct:

```
function Call()
{
    var fieldArray = [];

    this.AddFieldQuerysToArray = function(field, query) {
        // ...
        fieldArray.push(field);
    }
}
```

This creates a closure for each instance in which `fieldArray` is "kept alive" throughout the instance's lifetime.

Comment: "destroyed once your instance has been created" -- unless it's referenced from a closure

Comment: @JanDvorak The given code didn't give that suggestion, but I've added an example of such a condition.

Comment: I always find adding methods to `this` inside a constructor looks ugly, with the exception of something like `function Constr() {var env = {}; this.getEnv = function (x) {if (x) return env[x];return env;};}`

Comment: I still get the same 'cannot call method push of undefined' . I made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nQxqG/

Comment: @Jack if it's on the client side, it's visible. Also `a local variable which is destroyed once your instance has been created`, if only - `function Constr() {
    var secret = 'I am IRON MAN';
    this.find = function (x) {
        return eval(x);
    };
}
c = new Constr();
c.find('secret'); // "I am IRON MAN"`

Comment: @PaulS. That's no different from my answer, except that it's a more contrived example :)

Comment: @Kikimac Calling functions on the prototype directly only works if they don't use `this` to mean an instance of `Call`; you use either bind them to an instance using `.call()` or call the function on an instance instead; [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nQxqG/2/).

Comment: @PaulS. Also, with information hiding I mean that you can't directly access the information without going through the "accessor" methods. Of course, anyone can read the source code, that wasn't the point :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function Call() 
{
    this.fieldArray = [];
    this.queryArray = [];       
}


Call.prototype.AddFieldQuerysToArray = function(field,query)
{
    if(field !== 'undefined')
    {
        alert('field==='+this.fieldArray);
        this.fieldArray.push(field);
    }
    alert('field==='+this.fieldArray);  
    this.queryArray.push(query);
alert(this.queryArray);// to check
alert(this.fieldArray);// to check
};

field = 'exampleField';
query = 'exampleField';

var cally = new Call();
cally.AddFieldQuerysToArray(field,query); //change
```

The only problem is that you were calling `Call.prototype.AddFieldQuerysToArray()` method and here this value actually
referred to execution context of `Call.prototype` object which didn't have the arrays `fieldArray` and `queryArray`.

Calling the prototype method `AddFieldQuerysToArray()` by coding `cally.AddFieldQuerysToArray(field,query);` refers to the execution context
of the `cally` instance which has got both the arrays declared in it through its constructor.

Comment: alert(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Call.prototype));  This simple code will help you understand that fieldArray and queryArray arrays aren't actually  present in execution context of Call.prototype

Answer (score 0):

It's a very older post & the answer was given by Jack. `this` has to be used to avoid the Error.

But there's an **anti-pattern** used in the code block. `new Array()` should be avoided. Better approach is to use Array Literal Notation. Follow this StackOverflow answer [What’s the difference between "Array()" and "[]" while declaring a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/what-s-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar) for details.

But the gist is that if only one parameter is given to the Array constructor then that will interpreted as length of the Array but that will NOT BE THE FIRST element in the array.

```
console.log(new Array(10).length);//10
console.log(new Array(10)[0] === undefined);//true
```