# Array constructor "new Array()" can be overwritten and replaced with malicious code, how?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-security

We can create an array in a couple of ways:

```
var myArray = new Array();
```

Or:

```
var myArray = [];
```

The second way is safer to use than the new Array() syntax, because the Array constructor can be overwritten and potentially replaced with malicious code.

I have seen above lines in many JavaScript books but I don't understand how an `Array` constructor can be overwritten and replaced with malicious code? I'm looking for an example of how someone can do it, so that I can understand the reality of the issue.

Comment: With today's browsers   - you can do nothing with the ctor.

Comment: What do you mean by ctor?

Comment: Is little Freddy adding user-generated unfiltered html to his site? Bad little Freddy is going to get punished!

Comment: If your code can be injected with malicious code you've got bigger problems to deal with than `Array()`.

Comment: @Jack What if a third party library is hosted on a different server and they're injected with a malicious Array function. Not entirely your problem, but then again it is. All said, chances are minimal.

Comment: @KingKongFrog And you think that using `[]` is going to protect you against anything bad?

Comment: Never said that it would. This is a response to OP's question.  I myself, would use [] because it saves me keystrokes. :)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/931872/1338292

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in the code above:

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function (e){
  console.log("something wrong there");
  return(e);
};
```

Somewhere in the code below:

```
var i = [1,2,3,4,5];
i.forEach(function(e){
  console.log(e);
});
```

Output:

```
>"something wrong there"
```

As you can see, there is no difference how to initialize array variable. `var i = [];` just shorter notation.

Answer (score 0):

If you write on your JS console :

`[1,2,3]`

(just like that) -  you can do nothing with it.

Well that's not accurate with old browsers.

You could overload the array ctor by :

`Array = new function (){... }`

and so , when you got your friend list via Json ( not jsonp) :  -

someone could use an XSS/XSF attack and steal your friends list.

The thing ere is the fact that : if you write [1,2,3] - there is actually a ctor working here.

So if you got to a website which  does array response - he could still your list.