# jQuery push (array) not working

Tags: jquery, arrays, push

I have a jquery as below:

```
$('.cl').click(function(){
var selected_locations;
var loc_id = $('.a').val();
alert(loc_id);
selected_locations.push(loc_id);
alert(selected_locations);
});
```

And the `HTML` :

```
<input type="text" name="a" class="a" value="1" />
<a href="#" class="cl">Click</a>
```

But when I click on the link , though it displays the value of `loc_id`, it does not alerts thereafter, ie the value of the array `selected_locations` . Whats wrong ?
[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wwqu5/)

Comment: you can push anything in undefined variable ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to initialize it as a list. It is undefined by default;

```
var selected_locations = [];
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialize your array

```
var selected_locations = [];
```

and

```
alert(selected_locations.join());
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pJe6w/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

**[Declare a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/931875/1328612)**

```
var selected_locations = [];
```

or

```
var selected_locations = new Array();
```