# How do datatypes get their properties from Object?

Tags: javascript

For example; when you create an array in JavaScript, all [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)s prototype properties exists on it:

```
console.log(typeof [].valueOf); // function
```

I have read on several places that "almost everything is an object". I know the exceptions with primitive datatypes and how that works.

But what is actually meant by the quote? Is it that all datatypes prototype extends `object.prototype`? Or that they get an object wrapper?

I know that there are some similar threads, but I wouldn't say that they answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "datatypes".

> Everything is an object.

It means that everything - function, array, instance, host api, data structure, whatever - is an [*object*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28computer_science%29): A reference value with mutable properties.

> Is it that all datatypes prototype extends object.prototype?

That not what is meant by the quote, but it is true that most of the standard objects inherit properties (via the prototype chain) from `Object.prototype`.

Comment: What would I do without you Bergi

Answer (score 1):

It means that "everything" that is an object has a prototype/prototype chain that eventually resolves down to 'Object'.

Watch/play with http://www.objectplayground.com/ for a while and you'll get it. It is an excellent resource for these kinds of conversations.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: True. I just assumed that someone would have a better chance of articulating the answer here and wanted to provide this link because I found it extremely useful.

Comment: If you don't want to quote the important parts here, you should post the link as a comment. Link-only answers are not welcome here.

Comment: That link answers the question better than any text could ever hope to.

Answer (score 1):

You can test this for yourself (using the Node REPL, but will work in FF, Chrome, IE, etc)

```
> Object.prototype.test()
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'test'
    at repl:1:19
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1095:12)
> Array.prototype.test()
TypeError: Object  has no method 'test'
    at repl:1:18
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1095:12)
> Object.prototype.test = function(){console.log('test');}
[Function]
> Array.prototype.test()
test
undefined
>
> Object.prototype.test()
test
undefined
> String.prototype.test()
test
undefined
```

If the `Array` prototype didn't include the `Object` prototype, this wouldn't work -- everything that is an object in JavaScript eventually has the `Object.prototype` as it's "parent".

Answer (score 1):

Don't be confused by the shorthand syntax of `[]`.  Arrays can also be created using `new Array()` **(not recommended)**, which may seem like a more familiar syntax (You may recognize it from using function constructors).  When you investigate the prototype chain of the array using `Object.getPrototypeOf()` you always arrive at `Object`.  Which proves the point your readings were trying to make `Almost everything is an object`.

```
var arr = new Array();
var constructor = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(arr)).constructor;
alert(constructor);

//prints: function Object() {
//          [native code]
//        }

alert(constructor === Object.prototype.constructor);
//prints true
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ay56U/2/

Comment: Only one should never use `new Array()` when creating an array in JavaScript. The preferred syntax is the Array literal (just like when creating an object -- never do `new Object()`. References: [1](https://coderwall.com/p/h4xm0w), [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/whats-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar/1273936#1273936)

Comment: The __proto__ property is deprecated and should not be used.