# Is this javascript declaration an array or some kind of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Can someone please explain how the following javascript code:

```
var temp = {};

temp[0] = "a"
temp[1] = "b"
temp[2] = "c"
```

if different from an array like

```
var temp = new Array();
```

or

```
var temp = []
```

I don't really understand if the first example "temp = {}" can be considered an array or is it some kind of object?

Comment: js object is object array is also object

Comment: Have you searched the internet? I found this in like 1 minute, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYalKR2W-DU, http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89t1khd2(v=vs.94).aspx,

Comment: Presumably (?) the temp object is still an Object, not an Array, so it will NOT have a length property, nor the various Array methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var temp = {};` is an object with representation like `Object {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"}`
`var temp = []` is an array with representation like `["a", "b", "c"]`

while `var temp = new Array();` is again the same thing like `temp = []`

More detailed information here [What’s the difference between "Array()" and "[]" while declaring a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/whats-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar)

Answer (score 1):

The first one creates an object:

```
var temp = {};
```

The second one creates an array:

```
var temp = new Array();
```

In any case you can access them as they are an array:

```
var temp = {};
temp[1]="in object";
console.log(temp[1]);
```

same as

```
var temp = []
temp[1]="in array";
console.log(temp[1]);
```