# how to create an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried to create an array of objects but I can't make it work. Here is what I do:

```
var params = new Array();
console.log(params);
```

In the console, I see that params is indeed an array.

```
param = {
                begindate: '2014-02-28',
                begintime: '00:00:00',
                enddate: '2014-02-28',
                endtime: '23:59:59',
                type: 'abs',
                units: 'm3',
                steps: 'none',
                measureid: '1'};    
params.push(param);
console.log(params);
```

now in the console, I see that params is an object :(.

How can I do that so I have an array of objects?

Thanks,

John.

Comment: `params` is still an array, `param` is an object.

Comment: Yes, `params` is still an array. When you get something like this in the console: `[Object { begindate="2014-02-28", begintime="00:00:00", etc...}]`, the "Object" you're seeing is the object `param`, stored inside the array `params`; your code already successfully creates an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your browser's console window, you may be seeing:

```
[>Object]
```

You need to expand the output to see the array's objects. You may access the first index like so, which should output your param object:

```
console.log(params[0]);
```

Note I recommend referencing this to not use `new Array()` when possible:
[What’s the difference between "Array()" and "[]" while declaring a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/whats-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar)

Instead just initialize an array with `var params = [];`

Answer (score 1):

Params is Array
You can check it with:

```
console.log(params.constructor)
```