# Compare value inside object jquery

Tags: jquery, object, search

I build an object (jQuery) like this:

```
var arr = { items : [] };
$.each(arr, (function (key, value) {
    arr.items.push({
         id : key,
         param1 : "hello",
         param2 : "world !"
    });
});
```

What I want to do is to check before I push if I already have a record in my object with at least one identical id, param1 or param2.

I know I could insert an `$.each` before I push but there is probably a cleaner solution?

Comment: Your array syntax is invalid, you can't have `key:value` inside `[...]`.

Comment: u can use jQuery.inArray

Comment: Your `param1` and `param2` are always the same, so they will always be identical. Should those properties come from `value`?

Comment: @Barmar, sorry, my mistake i corrected. This is just an example, param1 and param2 can be identical like they can be different

Comment: @sakir how should i use $.inArray? Thanks.

Comment: Why is your array an object with another array inside it? Don't you mean  `var arr = [];`?

Comment: @Liam, can you write and example about how i should write my array? I always use to do like this

Comment: also `items.push` will produce a syntax error. again, don't you mean `arr.items.push`. May I suggest you get **this** code working before elaborating on it. Here's [inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) docs

Comment: [Array declaration in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/what-s-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar)

Comment: This is correct Liam, but thats because i tipped to fast, my actual code in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use objects to keep track of the values that have previously been seen.

```
ids = {};
param1s = {};
param2s = {};
$.each(array, function(key, value) {
    if (!(key in ids || value.param1 in param1s || value.param2s in param2s)) {
        items.push({
            id: key,
            value1: value.param1,
            value2: value.param2
        });
        ids[key] = true;
        param1s[value.param1] = true;
        param2s[value.param2] = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't just use : "value.id in arr.items.id || value.id in arr.items.param1 || value.id in arr.items.param2" ?

Comment: You only want to add to the result if the values are NOT already seen.