# Prompt for array and counter

Tags: javascript, html

Hello everyone I need help with my web scripting homework:
Function: Counter
Parameter: An array of Numbers.
Returns: The numbers of negative, zeros, and positive numbers in the array
Note: you must use a switch statement in the function.
This is what I have so far

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
<title>Exercise 4.11</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var num = new Array();
         num[0] = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number",""),10);
         num[1] = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number",""),10);
         num[2] = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number",""),10);
         num[3] = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number",""),10);
         num[4] = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number",""),10);

counter(num);

function counter(num) {

    var i,
      count = {
        negative: 0,
        zero: 0,
        positive: 0,
    };

for(i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
      switch (true) {
        case (num[i] < 0):
            count.negative++;
            break;

        case (num[i] === 0):
            count.zero++;
            break;

        case (num[i] > 0):
            count.positive++;
            break;

    }

}
document.write(count);
};
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see a question here. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: @ZachH with this `document.write(count);` I suppose :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity... where's your `<html>` tag?

Comment: `return count; document.write(count);` ? Print it before returning or print the `counter` after the function

Comment: Sorry everyone I wasn't very specific on what I needed thanks for you help so far but I am having trouble printing out the Negative, zero and positives from my counter

Comment: @user3765781 Sorry for being late to the party. I shared another (I find it better) example to achieve the needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong with this, but as you've not really asked a question I'll address them at random.

- you've created a method called `counter` for the task of processing the array, but you've not called it
- you're attempting to `document.write` after you've already exited the method by calling `return` first.
- your `prompts` will return strings, which need to be parsed into numbers using `parseInt`

A quick nudge in the right direction:

Call your `counter` method after you've prompted for the numbers, and change the syntax in the method declaration so that you can call it before it's defined:

```
var num = new Array();

num[0] = prompt("Please enter a number","");
num[1] = prompt("Please enter a number","");
num[2] = prompt("Please enter a number","");
num[3] = prompt("Please enter a number","");
num[4] = prompt("Please enter a number","");

counter(num);

function counter(num){

  // your logic

}
```

**Update**

At the end of your method, you'll want to print the results. As you've discovered, JavaScript is trying to describe the object you've asked it to print by converting it to a string. The string it ends up giving you is pretty uninsightful. What would be better is to print each individual key in the `count` object:

```
document.write(count.negative);
document.write(count.zero);
document.write(count.positive);
```

I would also look into using something other than [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write), but the reasons go beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: ok I see and then to print it out do I just document.write(count); at the end? I'm just getting [Object][object] as my output.

Comment: @user3765781 have updated my answer to address this.

Comment: only a minor improvement, but use `var num = [];` instead. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/what-s-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that your problem is that the `zero` property of your counter object is always 0, because the `prompt` function returns a `string` not a `number`. The `===` operator only returns `true` if the two objects being compared are exactly the same, whereas the `<` and `>` operators are a bit more flexible. You should either call `parseInt` on the values returned by `prompt`, or change your `case` statement. Here are examples of the two options:

### Option 1: ParseInt

```
num[0] = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number",""), 10);
```

### Option 2: Case Statement

```
case (num[i] == "0"):
```

These are two different approaches you could take. Do not combine them.

Comment: I completely forgot about parseInt thank you for that. I am mostly just having troubles now printing the results out.

Comment: @Shennan's answer covers that as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope I'm not late to the party.** Here's my 2c:

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/dekepa/3/)**

```
var count = {negative:0, zero:0, positive:0},
    i = 0 ;

(function ask(){
    var n = parseInt( prompt("Please enter a number",""), 10 );
    switch (true) {
      case (n<0):
        count.negative++;
        break;
      case (n===0):
        count.zero++;
        break;
      case (n>0):
        count.positive++;
        break;
      default: 
        alert( "Please use only Numbers!" );
        ask(); // Something went wrong... Ask again!
    }
    i++;
  if(i<5) ask();  // ASK 5 times

}()); // Start asking 

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(count, null, 4) ;
```

The above will immediately alert you if you did not used a number **and repeat the process!**
Also `parseInt` (10 is the radix param.) is needed to make sure to get a Number out of the prompt's String result.