# Why the script gives unexpected output

Tags: javascript, html

For the following snippet:

```
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
cars = ("BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford","Ranjith");
text="";
for(i=0;i<cars.length;i++)
{
 text+=cars[i] +"<br/>"
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>
</body>
```

Got the output as  :

```
R
a
n
j
i
t
h
```

The expected output was:

```
BMW
Volvo
Saab
Ford
Ranjith
```

What do I need change in my code to get the expected output. what is the reason for such output?

Comment: `cars` is not an array. The comma operator is left-associative and returns the RHS of its expression, thus the value of `cars` is the string `"Ranjith"`. Use square-brackets to make it an array: `cars=[values]`

Comment: @  blgt: thanks for the correct explanation

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/what-s-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cars` is not an array, please use `[]` to mark array variables. Try this:

```
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford","Ranjith"];
var text="";
for(i=0;i<cars.length;i++){
    text+=cars[i] +"<br/>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: why it happens when we use `()` instead of array `[]`

Comment: because in javascript you define array with `[]`and not `()`   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: small bracket `()` is using for function argument, default it's getting last array index in `car` variable

Answer (score 0):

```
var cars = new Array(10); // this will create  a 10 item long array with all slots containing undefined
```

or

```
var cars = [];
```

read [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)