# How to display random images in browser?

Tags: javascript

i want to display random images with js, my code as follows

```
var imageList=new Array();
imageList[0]="img1.jpg";
imageList[1]="img2.jpg";
imageList[2]="img3.jpg";
imageList[3]="img4.jpg";
var imageChoice=Math.floor(Math.random*imageList.length);
document.write('<img src="'+imageList[imageChoice]+'"'  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) is a method of the [`Math` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math). You're missing the brackets in order to call it as a function:

```
var imageChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageList.length);
```

As a side note, I would suggest initializing your image array [using square bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/what-s-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar) like this:

```
var imageList = ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg", "img4.jpg"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample select random color from one line of code!

```js
[].forEach.call($$("*"),function(a){
  a.style.outline="1px solid #"+(~~(Math.random()*(1<<24))).toString(16)
})
```

[check the detail from this link](http://arqex.com/939/learning-much-javascript-one-line-code?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email)