# new Array syntax, multiple parameters

Tags: javascript

Using bracket notation, you can initialize an array with zero or more values:

```
var a= [];              //length: 0, no items
var a= [1];             //length: 1, items: 1
var a= [1,2];           //length: 2, items: 1,2
```

Using `new Array()`, you can initialize an array with zero *or* two or more values:

```
var a= new Array(0);    //length: 0, no items
var a= new Array(1);    //length: 1, items: undefined
var a= new Array(1,2);  //length: 2, items: 1,2
```

Referring to the multiple-parameter syntax, in ***JavaScript: The Definitive Guide***, Flanagan writes:

> Using an array literal is almost always simpler than this usage of the
>   Array() constructor.

He doesn't provide any examples in which the multiple-parameter syntax *is* simpler, and I can't think of any.  But the words, "almost always" imply that there may be such instances.

Can you think of any?

Note that I understand the difference between the methods.  My question specifically is, Why would you ever use the multiple parameter syntax with `new Array()`?  Flanagan implies that there may be a reason.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/931875/3556874

Comment: @nicael.. not a duplicate

Comment: Maybe it's just an "escape phrase" (is that a word?), because he doesn't want to claim he is aware of every situation.

Comment: @FelixKling, I'm guessing you're right about that.

Comment: I agree with felix.. there is no difference while using multiple parameters

Comment: OTOH, are you sure he refers to multiple arguments? Because for one argument, I could see why one could argue that `new Array(10)` is simpler than `var arr = []; arr.length = 10;`.

Comment: I found the page online:  http://flylib.com/books/en/2.427.1.84/1/  Scroll down to the second bullet point, and you'll see that the quote refers specifically to the multiple-parameter syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only time you should use `new Array()` with *any* parameters is the single parameter case where you wish to create an (empty) array of the specified length.

There is no other case when `new Array()` with any number of parameters (including zero) is preferred over an array literal.

Indeed the array literal should be used wherever possible, because whilst it's possible to overwrite the function `Array()` so that it does something else (perhaps malicious) it's impossible to subvert the array literal syntax.

Comment: what are the useful cases to use `Array()`, when constructed **using multiple parameters** , not just while defining  an array of fixed size using a single parameter

Comment: @NoDownvotesPlz there aren't any - see clarification.

Comment: That was my assumption, and unless someone comes up with an example to the contrary, I'm accepting this answer.

Answer (score 2):

By simpler he is probably referring to the fact that it is shorter, easier to write, more explicit and you may have issues with things like:

```
var test = new Array(1) //Empty array 
var test2 = [1] //not empty
```

Comment: questions is not how it is different, Using an array literal is almost always simpler than this usage of the Array() constructor, **with multiple parameters**?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think he meant that there are cases where using the *multiple-parameter syntax* is simpler, but there are cases (only one I can think of) where using the Array constructor is simpler: Creating an array of size N.

Comment: Thanks, but the author is referring specifically to the multiple-parameter syntax when he writes, "almost always simpler."