# Javascript new Array() returns object type

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

```
app.factory('Shop', function() {
    var price = 0;
    var cart = new Array();
    return {
        totalPrice: function() { return price; },
        setTotalPrice: function(newPrice) { price = newPrice; },
        addToPrice: function(addedPrice) { price += addedPrice; },
        getCart: function() { return cart; },
        setCart: function(c) { cart = c; for (product in cart) { if (product.price) { addToPrice(product.price); } } },
        addToCart: function(product) { console.log(typeof(cart)); cart.push(product); addToPrice(product.price); },
        emptyCart: function() { cart = []; }
    };
});
```

this actually is angularJS, however I am initialising `cart = new Array();` and when I `console.log(typeof(cart));` it logs object. and also the `cart.push` fails with an error because it is of type object.

Any idea how I can get an actually array of it?

Comment: `var cart = [];` You're welcome.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll `typeof [] == object`

Comment: `typeof` everything in javascript is `object`. What you really want to check is `instanceof`

Comment: Do you call `setCart` with something other than an array at any point, that subsequent calls to `addToCart` then fail?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll `typeof 5`

Comment: @xCoder This answer to a possible duplicate question is the best I could find without reinventing the wheel: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1273936/384808

Comment: @royhowie I was exaggerating, but not by much. Sure, some primitives are not object types in javascript, but beyond that everything is.

Comment: Btw, neither `setCart` nor `emptyCart` does reset the `price`. You probably don't want that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What’s the difference between "Array()" and "\[\]" while declaring a JavaScript array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/what-s-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar)

Comment: @BrianDriscoll:  except for callable objects, of course :-)

Comment: @xCoder: "*the cart.push fails with an error because it is of type object.*" - can you please post the exact error message?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll I don't see how this is a duplicate.  It's not like the OP has misused `new Array()`?  Unless it's redeclared elsewhere that we can't see of course.

Comment: Error: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'cart.push(product)') is the exact error.

Comment: Have you checked to _ensure_ you're not calling `setCart` anywhere with something other than an array?  [Your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/ghv97sdm/) (with a `this.` before the calls to `addToPrice`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cart.push fails with an error because it is of type object.

That's not true. In JavaScript `typeof [] === typeof new Array() === 'object'`

[typeof operator MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Your code must fail for some other reason.

<sup>Edit:</sup>

> Error: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'cart.push(product)') is the exact error.

That probably means you've overwritten the variable `cart` somehwere and it's no longer an array.

`setCart: function(c) { cart = c; ...`

Could this be the culprit?

Comment: @xCoder Can I advise you to read this: [Chrome: Debugging JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging). Chrome Devtools make your life easier.