# Is "var foo = []" the same as "var foo = new Array()"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax

Is typing "var foo = []"  the same as typing  "var foo = new Array()"?

Comment: See a also http://stackoverflow.com/q/931872/615754

Comment: @RayonDabre—the OP (and others) may not get the satire. ;-) So many dupes, so little time…

Comment: @TedHopp, I take my words back as I am unable to find convincing document o defend my statement..`WebStorm` used to warn me in earlier days for `new Array()` but it must be because of some JSLints...

Comment: @RayonDabre—there is definitive proof that it isn't though, see [*ECMA-262 §22.1.1*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-constructor). ;-)

Comment: `new Array(n)` is helpful when you want to declare an empty array of n `undefined` element