# setValues cannot convert array to object[][]

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i've been coding this on the google apps script for a sheet:

```
  function basePesa(){
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("aux");
  var unique = sheet.getRange("C1").setFormula("=unique(A:A)");
 var Avals = sheet.getRange("C1:C").getValues();
 var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
 var transp = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("14Y3xiAa9kdoK_YO_tAVN-YWC9RE1EANV5wm8Ez1sa1o");
 var base =ss.getSheetByName("Base PESA");
 var values = base.getDataRange().getValues();
 var newdata = new Array(values.length);
 var y = 0;

//  Browser.msgBox(transp.length);

 for(var i=0;i<Alast;i++){


 var tra = Avals[i][0];

 for(var x =1; x<values.length;x++){

 if(values[x][18] == tra){
  newdata[y] = new Array(values[0].length);

 for(var p=0; p<values[0].length;p++)
 newdata[y][p] = values[x][p];   

 y++;
 }

 }   

  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Bco de Dados").getRange("A2:AZ"+(y+1)+"").setValues(newdata);
// Browser.msgBox(newdata);


}
```

It seems that I can't get to write the array into a range. I've checked if the ranges match as well as i'm certain that this array is a 2D one. Any instructions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you look what your array look like on debug mode ?

Comment: Yes, it looks like an 2D array .http://imgur.com/a/Vh3pB

Comment: Can you give us some access to a copy of this sheet, for testing purpose ?

Comment: I tried that before, I guess I can't since i'm in a work group and only those in it can access via sharing... :( I'll try to recreate it on another account, hang on

Comment: Btw, give it a try: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DOSPQS_4ZbEvQrFuNHeccicOzj2DDdz9Xxgv1OLB0WE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appear that the creation of the newdata array was the issue. Here is a sample which is working (I put the bad code in comment):

```
function basePesa(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("aux");
  var unique = sheet.getRange("C1").setFormula("=unique(A:A)");
  var Avals = sheet.getRange("C1:C").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
  var transp = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("14Y3xiAa9kdoK_YO_tAVN-YWC9RE1EANV5wm8Ez1sa1o");
  var base =ss.getSheetByName("Base PESA");
  var values = base.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newdata = [];//new Array(values.length);
  var y = 0;

  //  Browser.msgBox(transp.length);

  for(var i=0;i<Alast;i++){


    var tra = Avals[i][0];

    for(var x =1; x<values.length;x++){

      if(values[x][18] == tra){
        //newdata[y] = new Array(values[0].length);

        var test = [];

        for(var p=0; p<values[0].length;p++)
        {
          test.push(values[x][p]);
          //newdata[y][p] = values[x][p].toString(); 
        }

        newdata.push(test);

        y++;
      }

    }   

  }

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Bco de Dados").getRange("A2:AZ"+(y+1)+"").setValues(newdata);

  // Browser.msgBox(newdata);

}
```

Comment: Man, thanks so much, you rock! Even though i don't understand why that old code didn't work, yours is certainly welcome!

Comment: Take a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/what-s-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar), it may have a explaination.

Answer (score 7):

Array 1: [ A , B , C ] <---- Compatible for 1 Row, 3 Columns

Array 2: [ [A] , [B] , [C] ] <--- Compatible for 3 Rows, 1 Column

Array 3: [ [ A , B , C ] , [ A , B , C ] , [ A , B , C ] ] <--- Compatible for 3 Rows , 3 Columns**

**Important to note that the width of each smaller array within the larger array (in this case 3), must be the same for each of the smaller arrays.

[Click Here for a Visual Example (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVKPY.png)

Comment: Now I finally get my old issues with setValues, the 3 array pic examples are fantastic!  Many thanks

Comment: @user8637437: in the image the examples of Array 1 and Array 2 are inverted.

Answer (score 0):

Based on similar problem I had I guess that in the last row where you have

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Bco de Dados").getRange("A2:AZ"+(y+1)+"").setValues(newdata);
```

instead of

```
.setValues(newdata);
```

you should use

```
.setValues([newdata]);
```

Note the square brackets! This solution is basically the same (but shorter) as

```
...
var newdata = []
var test = []
...
test.push(values[x][p]
...
newdata.push(test)
...
....setValues(newdata)
```