# cannot access local variable inside subscriber call

Tags: typescript

Can someone explain to me why I am not able to access zvol_name inside subscriber call.

```
this.rest.get(this.volume_resource_name , {}).subscribe((res) => {
  let zvol_name: Array<String>;
  let zvol_object: Array<object>;
  for(let zvol_list of res.data) {
    zvol_name.push(zvol_list['vol_name']);
  }
  for(let j in zvol_name){
    var result = this.rest.get(this.volume_resource_name+ '/' + zvol_name['vol_name'], {})
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the line `let zvol_name: Array<String>;` does not actually initialize an array. Your `zvol_name` variable will still be `undefined`.

Initialize it with an empty array before using it:

```
let zvol_name: Array<String> = [];
```

You can set `"strictNullChecks": true` in your `tsconfig.json` file to make sure these errors get caught during compilation.

Comment: or `let zvol_name: Array<String> = new Array<String>();` See the difference here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/what-s-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar