# jQuery: Adding objects to arrays in each loops not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, push, each

I'm looping through DOM elements when a certain button is clicked. I've attached the class `finish-proc` to the button, so when clicked will activate this function:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.finish-proc', function () {
        var communities = [];

        var $this, $thisDay, input, inputDay, text, textDay, obj, objDay;

        $('.panel-default').each(function (i) {
            var maxPeople = '.' + $(this).attr('data-community') + '-max-people';
            var dayInfoRow = '.' + $(this).attr('data-community') + '-day-info';
            obj = {};
            obj["maxPeople"] = $(maxPeople).val();

            var daysArrayInLoop = [];

            $(dayInfoRow).each(function (j) {
                var objDay = {};

                var dayString = '.' + $(this).attr('data-community') + '-day-' + (j + 1);
                var dayStringStart = '.' + $(this).attr('data-community') + '-day-' + (j + 1) + '-start';
                var dayStringEnd = '.' + $(this).attr('data-community') + '-day-' + (j + 1) + '-end';

                objDay["dayString"] = $(dayString).val();
                objDay["dayStringStart"] = $(dayStringStart).val();
                objDay["dayStringEnd"] = $(dayStringEnd).val();

                daysArrayInLoop.push(objDay);
            }

            obj["dayArray"] = daysArrayInLoop;

            communities.push(obj);
        }
   }
</script>
```

This code is breaking on the line:

```
daysArrayInLoop.push(objDay);
```

With the error:

> daysArrayInLoop.push is not a function

Can anyone tell me why this is?

**EDIT** - I've tried to alter the `var daysArrayInLoop = [];` to `var daysArrayInLoop = {};`, still getting the same error

Comment: can you try with `daysArrayInLoop.push(1);` & see if it gives the same error. Also do `console.log(daysArrayInLoop)` before push & check if the console shows it is array. The code you have written is okay; it should work

Comment: Have you defined `dayInfoRow` anywhere?

Comment: Basically the array `daysArrayInLoop` is defined properly and is in scope at the time you use its `.push()` method. So there must be something else ..

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure the error is in the same exact line? Are you using `daysArrayInLoop` elsewhere in the page?

Comment: @sabithpocker yes, am definitely sure.

Comment: is this multi dimensioanl array to store?

Comment: did you try with `concat` instead of `push`? @VolcovMeter

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan it's an object holding other objects

Comment: Did you try with var objDay = new Array(); or var objDay = [];

Comment: @lalithkumar can you give me an example?

Comment: communities.concat(obj) like this @VolcovMeter

Comment: Did you try with var objDay = new Array(); or var objDay = []; ?

Comment: Can you post the HTML too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This code define array after push in object

```
var daysArrayInLoop = new Array();
    daysArrayInLoop.push(obj);
```

Comment: That did it. I don't understand how that worked rather than placing `var daysArrayInLoop = [];`

Comment: `function Array() {
    this.is = 'SPARTA';
}

var a = new Array();
var b = [];

alert(a.is);  // => 'SPARTA'
alert(b.is);  // => undefined
a.push('Woa'); // => TypeError: a.push is not a function
b.push('Woa'); // => 1 (OK)`

new Array() is create a new runtime array. No extra processing necessary at all

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/what-s-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and link reference! I understand now. :)