# Array not showing length

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Been trying for about an hour now, can't get my array to show its length upon a button press. It did show its length at one attempt, but it was a totally different amount to the amount of elements in the array. I read somewhere that it happens that way sometimes, and has something to do with undefined elements. But now it isn't showing any alerts at all.

```js
var fruits("Banana", "Apple", "Orange")

function myFunction() {
  alert(fruits.length)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <body>
    <script>
      src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" >
    </script>
    <script src="Arrays.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
</head>
<button id="lengthbutton" onclick="myFunction()"> Click me to find out length </button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: array is defined using `[ ]` brackets

Comment: Is that javascript inside a script tag?

Comment: ok, I'll try it with that

Comment: @JoshuaDuxbury , it is in a seperate js file

Comment: @JoshuaDuxbury , I've linked the source in between the head tags

Comment: You've closed your script tag <script> should be <script src="">

Comment: javascript [array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) check this

Comment: @Durga  thanks for the suggestion. Should've known to check W3schools.

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: @JoshuaDuxbury got it, will check the answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to declare an array using `()` you need to use `new Array()`:

```js
var fruits = new Array("Banana", "Apple", "Orange")

function myFunction() {
  alert(fruits.length)
}
```

```html
<button id="lengthbutton" onclick="myFunction()"> Click me to find out length </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var fruits = new Array("Banana","Apple", "Orange" );
var fruitsArr = ["Banana","Apple", "Orange" ];

function myFunction(arr) {
console.log(arr.length)
}

myFunction(fruits)
myFunction(fruitsArr)
```

You can create an array using array literal i.e `[]` or you can use `new Array()` to create an array.

Comment: Thanks, the square bracket option came in handy.

Comment: @draneol here you can get some [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/931875/3551786)

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your array declaration is `JavaScript` code is incorrect. It should be like.

```
var fruits = ["Banana","Apple","Orange"]
```

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Apple", "Orange"];

function myFunction() {
  alert(fruits.length)
}
```

```html
<button id="lengthbutton" onclick="myFunction()">Find Length of Array</button>
```

Comment: @draneol Its the way you are declaring your array, var fruits ("Banana","Apple", "Orange") is not the correct way of declaring array. Instead, you can declare array by two ways 1) using [ ] brackets (as I have used in example) 2) or using new keyword e.g. var fruits = new Array('a','b').

Answer (score 0):

The [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) literal syntax in JavaScript uses square brackets:

```
var fruits = [ "Banana","Apple", "Orange" ]
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, still isn't working after adding square brackets :(

Comment: You might have added just square brackets, have you changed the assignments also ?

Comment: Good point, I wasn't explicit about that but the equals sign is very important. Good eye, Nandan!

Answer (score 0):

```
var fruits = ["Banana","Apple", "Orange"]
```

Your code has something wrong.

Comment: It helps by describing what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `()` with `new Array()` **or** you can use `[]` if you do not want to declare it explicitly.
e.g.

```
var fruits = new Array("Banana", "Apple", "Orange")
```

**OR**

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Apple", "Orange"]
```

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Apple", "Orange"]

function myFunction() {
  alert(fruits.length)
}
```

```html
<button id="lengthbutton" onclick="myFunction()"> Click me to find out length </button>
```

**OR**

```js
var fruits = new Array("Banana", "Apple", "Orange")

function myFunction() {
  alert(fruits.length)
}
```

```html
<button id="lengthbutton" onclick="myFunction()"> Click me to find out length </button>
```