# How to make node-redis method execute with top priority in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, node-redis

Here's the code:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();
var addresses = new Array();

client.lrange('some_list', 0, -1, function(err, res) {
  console.log(res); #inner

  res.forEach(function(element) {
    if (result = element.match(/^(.+),(.*)$/)) {
      addresses.push(result[1]);
    }
  });
});

console.log(addresses); #outter
```

results in

```
[] #outter
['item1', 'item2', 'item3'] #inner
```

It turns out that the outside console log execute first then return null array. 
I want to get array result from node-redis lrange method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to see what `addresses` holds then you can try something like this:

```
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();
let addresses = new Array();
client.lrange('some_list', 0, -1, (err, res) => {
  console.log(res);
  res.forEach((element) => {
    if (result = element.match(/^(.+),(.*)$/)) {
      addresses.push(result[1]);
    }
  });
  console.log(addresses);
});
```

Comment: And you can use `let addresses = [];` instead of `let addresses = new Array();`, you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/what-s-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to get array result from node-redis lrange method and save it to a variable then use it in another function.

Comment: You are already saving the response from `lrange()` in `addresses` but the thing is that Node.js is asynchronous, that means that `client.lrange()` method will take some time to complete but Node.js won't stop from executing rest of the script and that's why `console.log(addresses);` gives an empty array.

Comment: So how to get the full array from outside?

Comment: you can do something like this:

`const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();

const someFunc = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     client.lrange('some_list', 0, -1, (err, res) => {
       if (err) {
          reject(err);
      }
      else {
        let addresses = [];
          res.forEach((element) => {
             if (result = element.match(/^(.+),(.*)$/)) {
               addresses.push(result[1]);
            }
         });
        resolve(addresses);
      }
  });
  });
}`

Comment: I want to use the addresses outside the lrange method but not in, that's why I console log the addresses at the outside end.

Comment: After revised your code, things get to work, thank you.

Comment: You can use `.then()` or `await` it inside other `async` function to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
const driver = await redis.lRange("allDriverList", 0, -1);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.