# Why are Arrays with the same syntax defined differently - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I was debugging one day when I came across this case in JavaScript.

```
var arrayA = [1, , 1],
    arrayB = [1, void 0, 1];
```

Now at first glance `arrayA` and `arrayB` look similar but when I tried this code in the **Google Chrome Developer Console**, things got weird:

[image: Defining Array A and Array B]

As you can see here, `arrayB` (the second one) has all it's members listed, including the `undefined` element.

But it's not the same with `arrayA`, ignoring the second member (`arrayA[1]`) even though it's `undefined`.

There's a problem here when it comes to how `arrayA` and `arrayB` are indexed, even though they are practically the same.

[image: Indexing Array A]

Everything is fine and dandy when iterating through `arrayA` using `for` and `for...of` statements but when using the `for...in` statement, the array's second element (`arrayA[1]`) is skipped over.

[image: Indexing Array B]

However, every element of `arrayB` was recognized when using all `for` loop variations.

This has also been tested on **Mozilla Firefox** and **Microsoft Edge** as well with the same results.

Is there any explanation for why this is so? Why is `arrayA` treated differently (no matter how slightly) from `arrayB` — using `for...in` statements?

I apologize if the images aren't ideal, they were just to show I was using the **Google Chrome Developer Console**.

And my thanks in advance for anyone willing to answer the question.

> **EDIT**
>
> Just to add, the custom `depth` property in the arrays do not have any effect on the arrays, even without them I still get the same result.

Comment: console.log(Array(100))

Comment: Arrays with empty slots are different to arrays that have slots filled with `undefined`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44471705/3001761. Methods like `forEach` are [explicitly documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) as not including uninitialised elements.

Comment: It seems you are on to something, @epascarello. I just tried the code and it has the same behavior as the arrays in the question. Any idea why?

Comment: Because `Array(size)` also creates an array containing `size` empty slots.

Comment: sounds like you can use `array.hasOwnProperty(n)` to split the hairs you need.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I'm just now learning that there are **Sparse Arrays** in JavaScript. I think I'll be avoiding them most of the time though as I can't easily see a use case for them right now.

Answer (score 3):

Your arrayB is what arrays usually look like, they are filled with values.

However, your method ( as well as using `Array(n)`) can create sparse arrays, array in which some of the values are missing. Arrays, after all, are only special objects meaning that they are key values collection so your first array looks like

```
{"0": 1, "2": 1 }
```

while your second looks like

```
{"0": 1, "1": undefined, "2": 1}
```

The way to see it is to consider sparse arrays a quirk of the language and avoid it because they don't really have a use case. If you want an array, don't make it sparse, otherwise, use an object ( or an ES6 Map / Set, according to your use case)

Answer (score 3):

`empty` is used to distinguish that there is actually no key at that position (for...in enumerates the keys):

```js
var arrayA = [1, , 1], arrayB = [1, void 0, 1];
    
console.log( { ...arrayA } );   // { "0": 1, "2": 1 }
console.log( { ...arrayB } );   // { "0": 1, "1": undefined, "2": 1 }

console.log( 1 in arrayA );   // false
console.log( 1 in arrayB );   // true

console.log( JSON.stringify(arrayA) );   // "[1,null,1]"
console.log( JSON.stringify(arrayB) );   // "[1,null,1]"
```

---

As a side note, JavaScript `Array` is just an object where the positive integer keys are used :

```js
var a = []
a[1] = 1
a.b = 'c'
a[-1] = -1
a[.1] = .1
    
console.log( a );   // [undefined, 1] but DevTools shows "►(2) [empty, 1, b: "c", -1: -1, 0.1: 0.1]
console.log( { ...a } );   // { "1": 1, "b": "c", "-1": -1, "0.1": 0.1 }
console.log( JSON.stringify(a) );   // "[null,1]"
```

(but that is not the case for [`TypedArray`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray))