# What's the difference between using Array.of() compared with brackets [ ]?

Tags: javascript

For example,

```
let x = [1,2,3,5];
```

is equivalent to:

```
let x = Array.of(1,2,3,4,5);
```

(Unless I'm missing an important detail, which is why I'm asking the question)

You could also mix these with spread `...` syntax and variables and thus other arrays. To me, it seems `Array.of()` has more overhead. Would `Array.of()` have to parse an arguments object into another array?

I know there's also `new Array()` as others have before questioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/931872/3967379), but that has a different semantic purpose, so I don't see this question as a duplicate to that.

As I see it now, `Array.of()` and `[ ]` seem redundant. The function's intent does seem more explicit on the former, but the latter's intent is simple enough to not be misunderstood.

So to summarize:

- When is one preferable over the other?
- Why does `Array.of()` exist when JavaScript survived without it for so long?
- And, what're the differences of these two methods, if any? Would there be any needless overhead?

Comment: I link that post in my question for reference.

Comment: If you don't consider your question a duplicate you might simplify to ask a clearly different question. As it is you're covering some of the same ground, I think.

Comment: One of the links now is a rightful duplicate. I did search across Google and here somewhat extensively but could not find one. Sorry, all! I guess engines don't like brackets.