# Javascript : Display value of key from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array "Group":

[image]

i would like to have the value of name (test01) but i have undefined with console.log(group['name']), console.log(group[name]) or console.log(group.name).

How i can display the value ?

Thanks

Comment: It's an array of objects: group[1].name should work

Comment: Do 'console.log(group)' just to make what group is

Comment: you are using an array as if it's an object which isn't good practice since array.prototype contributes some properties. this can lead to bugs if you frequently use arrays incorrectly like this. Use an object and if it still doesn't work ask again.

Comment: Please post the actual output and the code you're working with instead of a picture of the console. Console emissions are implementation-dependent and often unclear.

Comment: I was wondering how that console output could happen. It shows an empty array but  the expanded view shows properties. I'm guessing that this array is being mutated by asynchronous functions so it has these properties at certain times but does not have them at other times...

Comment: Good guess, but it seems unclear until the code and actual data structure shows up. It looks like Chrome, but usually when you set properties on an array you see them as key-value pairs like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56190829).

Comment: I have replicated this behavior in the console: https://puu.sh/E2vGp/ea79e4eafc.gif
It's caused by mutating the array after displaying it, and then expanding it after mutating it.

Comment: Nice. Even so, OP accepted a solution that made an assumption about an object as a child of the array, so it's all a total mystery as to how OP actually came to get this screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an array of objects - access the specific object first using `group[0]` then access the property you want with `group[0].name`.

```js
const group = [{ name: "test01" }];

const res = group[0].name;

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have you can call your propriety if it's an object or an array of objects.

```js
const object = {
  name: "test1",
  group: "c2"
}

console.log(object.name)

const array = [{
  name: "test1",
  group: "c2"
}]

console.log(array[0].name)
```